# What can I use instead of the arrow operator, `->`?

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the arrow operator (`->`) a synonym for?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The following two expressions are equivalent:

```
a->b

(*a).b
```

(subject to operator overloading, as Konrad mentions, but that's unusual).

Comment: Overloading issues are a lot less unusual than you think. Not long ago, STL implementors had no overloaded `->` operator for some iterator types so you *had* to use `*.`. Many libraries define them inconsistently. Becomes really annoying when you work with templates and don't know the precise type.

Comment: you can also do `a[0].b` instead of `(*a).b`. But it wouldn't be as properly structured.

Comment: Boy, after many years of c# programming, going back to c++ is not only cognitively taxing, the c++ syntax is just ugly and yucky. 

I feel like taking a shower after using it. Programs written in c and c++ just encourage bad programming. Apple, pre-unix, struggled to make the language as pretty as Pascal.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I'd argue that a lot of the ugly stuff isn't considered idiomatic anymore, but unfortunately that doesn't mean you can afford to not be familiar with it as a practicing C++ programmer. Also the syntactically nice path is often not the semantically nice path, but that also has been getting better not worse. But then again I have C++ Stockholm Syndrome.

Comment: @TimSeguine  If you ever want to see pretty code, then look at the documentation for inside the Macintosh.  I think they invented CamelCase.  Very descriptive variable names and elegantly formatted code. They managed to make their later C code almost as gorgeous as their earlier Pascal code.

Answer (score 74):

`a->b` is generally a synonym for `(*a).b`. The parenthesises here are necessary because of the binding strength of the operators `*` and `.`:  `*a.b` wouldn't work because `.` binds stronger and is executed first. This is thus equivalent to `*(a.b)`.

Beware of overloading, though: Since both `->` and `*` can be overloaded, their meaning can differ drastically.

Comment: By `binding strength` you mean operator precedence? if not what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @Vizkrig Yes, the two terms are used interchangeably (although “operator precedence” seems to be much more frequent, at least in recent years).

Answer (score 47):

The C++-language defines the arrow operator (`->`) as a synonym for dereferencing a pointer and then use the `.`-operator on that address.

For example:

If you have a an object, `anObject`, and a pointer, `aPointer`:

```
SomeClass anObject = new SomeClass();
SomeClass *aPointer = &anObject;
```

To be able to use one of the objects methods you dereference the pointer and do a method call on that address:

```
(*aPointer).method();
```

Which could be written with the arrow operator:

```
aPointer->method();
```

The main reason of the existents of the arrow operator is that it shortens the typing of a very common task and it also kind of easy to forgot the parentheses around the dereferencing of the pointer. If you forgot the parentheses the .-operator will bind stronger then *-operator and make our example execute as:

```
*(aPointer.method()); // Not our intention!
```

Some of the other answer have also mention both that C++ operators can be overload and that it is not that common.

Comment: `new SomeClass()` returns a pointer (`SomeClass *`), not the `SomeClass` object. And you start with declaring `anObject` and `aPointer` but you're using `p` afterwards.

Comment: overall this explanation is theoretically very apt, only the change of objects makes it a little convoluted. But the process is better described

Answer (score 19):

In C++0x, the operator gets a second meaning, indicating the return type of a function or lambda expression

```
auto f() -> int; // "->" means "returns ..."
```

Comment: Technically specking it is no longer an "operator" there, or is it?

Comment: @Martin most people use the word "operator" for many things that aren't directly used for computing values. Like for "::" ("scope operator"). I don't know what the point of view of the standard is on this, exactly. In an abstract sense, one could view "->" as a functional operator mapping a sequence of types (parameters) to a return type, like the haskell operator, which is written "->" too.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `::` is actually an operator, like `.` or `->`, and is called "scope resolution operator" in the standard.

Answer (score 13):

I mostly read it right-to-left and call "in"

```
foo->bar->baz = qux->croak
```

becomes:

"baz in bar in foo becomes croak in qux."

Answer (score 3):

`->` is used when accessing data which you've got a pointer to.

For example, you could create a pointer ptr to variable of type int intVar like this:

```
int* prt = &intVar;
```

You could then use a function, such as foo, on it only by dereferencing that pointer - to call the function on the variable which the pointer points to, rather than on the numeric value of the memory location of that variable:

```
(*ptr).foo();
```

Without the parentheses here, the compiler would understand this as `*(ptr.foo())` due to operator precedence which isn't what we want.

This is actually just the same as typing

```
ptr->foo();
```

As the `->`dereferences that pointer, and so calls the function `foo()` on the variable which the pointer is pointing to for us.

Similarly, we can use `->` to access or set a member of a class:

```
myClass* ptr = &myClassMember;
ptr->myClassVar = 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use -> to define a function.

```
auto fun() -> int
{
return 100;
}
```

It's not a lambda. It's really a function. "->" indicates the return type of the function.