# An array of structures within a structure - what's the pointer type?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following declaration in a file that gets generated by a perl script ( during compilation ):

```
 struct _gamedata
{

 short res_count;
 struct
 {
  void * resptr;
  short id;
  short type;
 } res_table[3];
}
_gamecoderes =
{
 3,
 {
  { &char_resource_ID_RES_welcome_object_ID,1002, 1001 },
  { &blah_resource_ID_RES_another_object_ID,1004, 1003 },
{ &char_resource_ID_RES_someting_object_ID,8019, 1001 },
 }
};
```

My problem is that `struct _gamedata` is generated during compile time and the number of items in `res_table` will vary. So I can't provide a type declaring the size of `res_table` in advance.

I need to parse an instance of this structure, originally I was doing this via a pointer to a char ( and not defining `struct _gamedata` as a type. But I am defining `res_table`.

e.g.

```
char * pb = (char *)_gamecoderes; 
                           // i.e. pb points to the instance of `struct _gamedata`.
short res_count = (short *)pb;
pb+=2;
res_table * entry = (res_table *)pb;
for( int i = 0; i < res_count; i++ )
{
    do_something_with_entry(*entry);
}
```

I'm getting wierd results with this. I'm not sure how to declare a type `_struct gamedata` as I need to be able to handle a variable length for `res_table` at compile time.

Comment: So are you programming in C or C++? I doubt you're somehow programming in both. The code you have looks very C to me.

Comment: @GMan - I'm compiling the code with a C++ compiler, and the majority is written in C++. However the `gamedata` struct is auto generated by a perl script and was originally intended to be compiled in C. I am considering altering the perl script to declare a `std::vector` rather than an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Ideally use `memcpy(3)`, at least use type `_gamedata`, or define a protocol

We can consider two use cases. In what I might call the programmer-API type, serialization is an internal convenience and the record format is determined by the compiler and library. In the more formally defined and bulletproof implementation, a protocol is defined and a special-purpose library is written to portably read and write a stream.

The best practice will differ depending on whether it makes sense to create a versioned protocol and develop stream I/O operations.

#### API

The best and most completely portable implementation when reading from compiler-oject serialized streams would be to declare or dynamically allocate an exact or max-sized `_gamedata` and then use `memcpy(3)` to pull the data out of the serial stream or device memory or whatever it is. This lets the compiler allocate the object that is accessed by compiler code and it lets the developer allocate the object that is accessed by developer (i.e., `char *`) logic.

But at a minimum, set a pointer to `_gamedata` and the compiler will do everything for you. Note also that `res_table[n]` will always be at the "right" address regardless of the size of the `res_table[]` array. It's not like making it bigger changes the location of the first element.

#### General serialization best practice

If the `_gamedata` object itself is in a buffer and potentially misaligned, i,e., if it is anything other than an object allocated for a `_gamedata` type by the compiler or dynamically by a real allocator, then you still have potential alignment issues and the only correct solution is to `memcpy(3)` each discrete type out of the buffer.

A typical error is to use the misaligned pointer anyway, because it works (slowly) on x86. But it may not work on mobile devices, or future architectures, or on some architectures when in kernel mode, or with advanced optimizations enabled.  It's best to stick with real C99.

#### It's a protocol

Finally, when serializing binary data in any fashion you are really *defining a protocol*. So, for maximum robustness, don't let the compiler define your protocol. Since you are in C, you can generally handle each fundamental object discretely with no loss in speed. If both the writer and reader do it, then only the developers have to agree on the protocol, not the developers and the compilers and the build team, and the C99 authors, and Dennis M. Ritchie, and probably some others.

Answer (score 7):

Since the struct is anonymous, there's no way to refer to the type of this struct. (`res_table` is just the member name, not the type's name). You should provide a name for the struct:

```
struct GameResult {
        short type;
        short id;
        void* resptr;
};

struct _gamedata {
        short res_count;
        GameResult res_table[3];
};
```

Also, you shouldn't cast the `data` to a `char*`. The `res_count` and `entry`'s can be extracted using [the `->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c). This way the member offsets can be computed correctly.

```
_gamedata* data = ...;
short res_count = data->res_count;
GameResult* entry = data->res_table;
```

or simply:

```
_gamedata* data;
for (int i = 0; i < data->res_count; ++ i)
   do_something_with_entry(data->res_table[i]);
```

Comment: that struct gets generated during compilation. I don't know how big `res_table` is going to get and thus am having problems defining the type as you suggest.

Comment: @BeeBand: Which C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: it's a third party tool based on g++.

Comment: @BeeBand: In that case, you could get the type using `typeof(data->res_table) entry = data->res_table;`. However, you still cannot write the prototype of the `do_something_with_entry` function.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is alignment.  There will be at least two bytes of padding in between `res_count` and `res_table`, so you cannot simply add two to `pb`.  The correct way to get a pointer to `res_table` is:

```
res_table *table = &data->res_table;
```

If you insist on casting to `char*` and back, you must use `offsetof`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
...
res_table *table = (res_table *) (pb + offsetof(_gamedata, res_table));
```

Note: in C++ you may not use `offsetof` with "non-POD" data types (approximately "types you could not have declared in plain C").  The correct idiom -- without casting to `char*` and back -- works either way.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zack points out, there is padding between elements of your structure.

I'm assuming you have a char* because you've serialized the structure (in a cache, on disk, or over the network).  Just because you are starting with a `char *` doesn't mean you have to access the entire struct the hard way.  Cast it to a typed pointer, and let the compiler do the work for you:

```
_gamedata * data = (_gamedata *) my_char_pointer;
for( int i = 0; i < data->res_count; i++ )
{
    do_something_with_entry(*data->res_table[i]);
}
```