# What is "->" in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I've seen this operator pop up quite a few times in example code in "Learn Objective C on the Mac."

I believe it's an operator in the C language which Objective C inherits.
I tried Googling and searching Stack Overflow and oddly nothing came up.

Does it have an English name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has to do with structures.

When we have a struct available locally on the stack, we access its members with the `.` operator.  For example:

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(42,42);
NSLog(@"%f", p.x);
```

However, if we instead have a *pointer* to a structure, we have to use the `->` operator:

```
CGPoint *p = malloc(1*sizeof(CGPoint));
p->x = 42.0f;
NSLog(@"%f", p->x);
free(p);
```

Comment: We don't have to, we can use `(*p).x` instead.

Comment: @jer sure, but I'm of the opinion that `p->x` is a lot simpler to read than `(*p).x`.

Answer (score 10):

`->` is **not** specific to Objective-C. It's a C operator.

Now that's cleared, it's the member access operator, equivalent to a pointer dereference and then using the dot operator on the result.

Say you had a `struct` like this:

```
typedef struct Person {
   char *name;
} Person;

Person *jacob = malloc(1*sizeof(Person));
```

So this statement:

```
jacob->name = "Jacob";
```

Is equivalent to this statement:

```
(*jacob).name = "Jacob";
```

Of course, don't forget the `free`:

```
free(jacob);
```

Comment: When you say it is equivalent to *, it isn't really. It is equivalent to dereferencing then accessing using .

Comment: @Mitch, No, I actually meant that.

Comment: Perhaps create a Person struct and assign then, for complete correctness.

Answer (score 9):

In C

```
a->b
```

is a shortcut for

```
(*a).b
```

which is for dereferencing of members of a struct that is pointed to.

This is useful, because of . binds stronger than the dereferencing operator * . So by using -> you avoid having to use these ugly parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

It's a member selection (or access) equivalent to a pointer de-reference (as pointed out in comments)

`a->member` is equivalent to `(*a).member` in C/C++

Comment: As a corollary to the above, it's the same thing as it is in C.

Comment: I think that the downvote is because you said that it's a pointer de-reference, while actually the pointer dereference operator is the usual `*`; the C99 standard calls it "member access operator" as the dot (`.`) (§6.6.9). I'd just say that it's a shorthand for the `(*a).Member` notation.

Comment: (Changed `Property` to `member`, since `Property` has a different meaning in Objective-C)

Answer (score 4):

[The same thing that it means in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c). It can be used to access the instance variables of objects directly, but generally this is not the best practice. The dot notation you're referring to is a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html), not the usual C dot notation.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that `self->bla` (or plain `bla`) accesses the ivar directly, while `self.bla` accesses it through the property accessors.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of implied in my answer. In particular, you can't use `self.bla` to access an instance variable because `self` is a pointer to the object in memory. That's why you have to use `->`. And that's why there's no conflict between C dot notation and Obj-C properties :)

Answer (score 2):

`a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`, and designates member `b` of the object pointed to by `a`.

In the C standard, it is called the "structure/union pointer operator," which isn't really the catchiest name.

Answer (score 2):

It's the "indirect member access operator". It's a C operator, which both Objective-C and C++ inherited.

This

```
a->b
```

is equivalent to:

```
(*a).b
```

but is less typing. (The parens are necessary in the expanded form due to precedence of `*` and `.`.)

Answer (score 2):

It's all been said, it is a shortcut for accessing members of a struct pointer, but just a note to add that you can access ivars using the same syntax due to the way the Objective-C runtime works:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
   NSString *something;
}

/* ... SNIP ... */

NSLog(@"something = %@", foo->something); // Where foo is an instance of the Foo class
```

This is handy when you need to access ivars that aren't exposed by methods; specifically when you need to implement `copyWithZone:` on your objects.

Comment: thats ok but can you tell me what does this mean.                         loginViewController->mPortSIPSDK    = mPortSIPSDK;
                                                                         first mportSIPSDK is instance of PORTSIPSDK which is declared in  loginviewcontroller.Second is  ie(=mPortSIPSDK)is declared in aoodelegate.