# Objective-C -> symbol?

Tags: objective-c, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “->” in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486048/what-is-in-objective-c)

what is the "->" in objective-c?
And what is it used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same as in C. Objective-C is a strict superset of C, so it inherits all the syntax. In C:

```
x->y
```

is the same as:

```
(*x).y
```

The syntax `*x` dereferences the pointer `x`, and `.` accesses a property on the result of the dereferencing.

Answer (score -1):

-> is for Accessing instance variables (Pointers)

Comment: `->` is very very rarely used to access instance variables. Can be done, but no one does it that way.  `->` is most often seen in the traditional C role.