# What does the -> mean in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can Anyone explain what this means:

```
oauth->url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"https" host:host path:unencodedPath];
```

It is variable assignment but why does it use '->' is this something to do with it being a Class method?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486048/what-is-in-objective-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It references the instance variable `url` of the `oauth` instance. It is pure C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing it means in C/C++.  Objective C objects don't use -> but C/C++ classes do.

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought Objective-C classes could use this syntax, especially to instanciate readonly values. Is it true?

Comment: I have never seen it done, but that doesn't mean you are wrong.  I'm sure I'll find out eventually :)

Comment: Yes as it turns out they can be used as Friedrik said I am looking at a library that uses it now

Comment: normally you would only be setting read-only ivars within "self", in which case you would not need to, but _could_ say `self->url =`, but in the case of a tightly cooperating class or classes that directly set the value of another instance's state the `oauth->url =` syntax is required to do so.  there are other design choices that would not require this syntax, including private accessor methods