# What does "->" mean in objective-c ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is "->" in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486048/what-is-in-objective-c)

Sometimes I see myObject->dummyLabel. We can use a pointer with dot notation. Why do we use -> ?

Comment: @BoltClock: yes, duplicate, but I find it strange that none of those answers mention instance variables...