# Objective C syntax: what is ->?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “->” in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486048/what-is-in-objective-c)

beginner question here. Im looking through this intro to the objective c runtime (http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-13-intro-to-the-objective-c-runtime.html) and I see this funky syntax with a ->. Can't seem to find an explanation on what that means.

Easy points anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: `->` is also known as the ["structure dereference" operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators).

Comment: (I found the duplicate question using the afore-mentioned keywords: "obj-c structure dereference". It is good to first look up the "real name" for something, which I did with searching for "C operator list" initially.)

Comment: Objective-C is C.  Maybe you should invest in an introductory C programming book/tutorial/class/video/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually C syntax. It's used to access a field (variable) of a pointer to a struct.

When you have a pointer, you have to use the `*` syntax to dereference it:

```
int var = 1;   // regular int variable
int *ptr = &var;  // pointer to that variable
int sum = (*ptr) + 3;   // if you want to use it regularly, you have to dereference it first.
```

Now, if this pointer happens to be a struct pointer, it can become ugly:

```
// Define and typedef a struct.
typedef struct {
    int num1;
    int num2; 
} MyStruct;

MyStruct myStruct = (MyStruct){1, 2};   // Regular struct.
MyStruct *pointer = &myStruct;          // Pointer to that struct.
int sum = (*pointer).num1 + (*pointer).num2;   // The ugly part.
int niceSum = pointer->num1 + pointer->num2;   // Same thing with cleaner code.
```

Comment: And in Objective-C and object is a struct and so `->` can be used to access instance variables declared public in the interface. However most will encourage you to use properties and avoid publicly accessible instance variables.