# What Is Difference Between -> And . In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am New in Objective-c
During Coding I am Come across code like  self->address  and self.name
1)what is -> and . (they are operator or something else)
2)what is difference between Them
3)how to decide which one is used

If possible then please give small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is `->` and `.` (are they operators or something else)?

Both `->` and `.` are operators, [of the same (highest) precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

> what is the difference between them?

`->` takes a pointer+field; `.` takes a struct+field, or a pointer+property that has an accessible getter.

> how to decide which one to use?

This is implied by the sides of the operation, in the sense that, in the absence of name collisions, you wouldn't get into a situation when both operators could be used without causing a compile-time error. When you have a pointer and a field, use `->` operator; otherwise, use `.`

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight for your answer and quick reply

Comment: If you have a property and an accessible instance variable with the same name, both operators will work, but the results are different.  You should also have no reason to use the `->` operator with Objective-C classes, though it does come up in rare cases.

Comment: @Avi That's precisely the reason why I said "in the absence of name collisions".

Comment: @Avi As far as suggesting that there should be no reason to use `->` goes, I am reluctant to do so, for the same reason that I stay away from discussions of individual statements and operators in programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `object.name` you are calling a method called `name` on `object`. This method may access an instance variable that it then returns, but it is a method, so it can do whatever it is written to do. Objective-C Synthesises methods for properties, so you may not have actual Objective-C code, but the methods still exist and can be overridden.

With `object->name` you are access the instance variable `name` of `object`. This is a direct access to the memory of `object` thus there is no method call and nothing to implement / override.

In general, for object's, you should use `object.name` to access the property unless there is a specific reason no to do this.

As a note, when you reference an instance variable inside of an object itself it is dereferencing `self` implicitly, i.e. `name` is the same as `self->name`.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is an operator used to access members of a struct. However, in Objective-C, it is also used to access properties of a class (via accessors). So, in your example, `self.name` is used to access a property called `name` in your class.

`->` is a dereference operator from C. It is used to access members of a struct via a pointer to it. In Objective-C, it can also be used to access members of a class. In your example, `self->address` is used to access a member variable (so called ivar) named `address` in your class.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4486072/285242).