# What is this operator(->) in C?

Tags: c, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

As far as i know only C++ can use classes(obj->something) however i have seen this operator in  numerous C applications.

And a small side-question. Usually one uses structures in C like this:

```
structname.somevariable
```

However i have seen them used like:

```
structname.something1.something2
```

Does it have something to do with the keyword union?

Comment: see [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/)

Comment: It becomes easier to understand when you realize that classes and structures are almost the same thing. You can access the members of a struct just like you access the members of a class.

Comment: It is possible to use `obj.something` in C++ too.

Comment: @Andres: What classes? The question is tagged C

Answer (score 7):

```
struct A
{
    int b;
};

struct A *a;

a->b  ==  (*a).b;
```

And no, that has nothing to do with unions. It's just getting a member of a member.

Comment: @dikidera: It dereferences the pointer `a` and accesses the member named `b` in the struct or union.

Comment: @Mehrdad: you forgot a semicolon after the struct definition :)

Answer (score 5):

if you have a pointer to a struct object, like

```
 struct P * p;
```

you access members with `->`

```
 p->member
```

if p is not a pointer, you access members with `.`

```
struct P p;
p.member
```

***Any*** C book covers this :P

Answer (score 2):

Operator `->` is used to access a member of a `struct` through a pointer to that structure. The second part of your question is used when accessing nested structures, it is not restricted to the use of unions. For instance:

```
struct A {
  int a;
};

struct B {
  struct A baz;
};

int main() 
{
  struct A foo;
  struct B bar;

  (&foo)->a = 10;

  bar.baz.a = 20;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ `class`es are an extension of C `struct`s, and an object is just a pointer to a `struct`.  C++ didn't actually invent a whole lot of new stuff; it's called C **++** for a reason.

`struct`s can be nested.  Given

```
struct a {
    int a_a;
    int a_b;
}

struct b {
    int b_a;
    struct a b_b;
} a;
```

you can refer to `a.b_b.a_b`.

A `union` uses similar syntax to a `struct`, but all the members overlap each other.  This is useful when you need to interpret a chunk of memory in multiple ways.

I strongly suggest picking up a C book.

Answer (score 0):

x.y.z is used when you want to access a member of a struct that is itself a member of another struct.

```
typedef struct _POINT
{
    int x;
    int y;
} POINT;

typedef struct _RECT
{
    POINT topLeft;
    POINT bottomRight;
} RECT;

int main()
{
    RECT r;
    r.topLeft.x = 0;
    t.topLeft.y = 0;

    int width = r.bottomRight.x - r.topLeft.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small example in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a_t {
    int a;
    /* ... */
};

struct b_t {
    struct a_t a;
    /* ... */
};

int main()
{
    struct a_t a;
    struct a_t *b;
    b = malloc(sizeof(struct a_t));
    a.a = 1;
    b->a = 2;
    printf("%d; %d;\n", a.a, b->a); 
    (&a)->a = 3;
    (*b).a = 4;
    printf("%d; %d;\n", a.a, b->a);
    free(b);

    struct b_t c;
    c.a.a = 5;
    printf("%d;\n", c.a.a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, in C++

```
class IDENTIFIER {
    // stuff, possibly including functions
};
```

is **exactly** the same as

```
struct IDENTIFIER {
    private:
    // stuff, possibly including functions
};
```

---

and

```
struct IDENTIFIER {
    // stuff, possibly including functions
};
```

is **exactly** the same as

```
class IDENTIFIER {
    public:
    // stuff, possibly including functions
};
```