# What does this means in C? AB->CD->Func(param)

Tags: c

Ok let me explain a little more. I have a pointer to structure `AB` type `struct1` inside the structure there is a pointer to another structure called `CD` of type `struct2` and the definition of `struct2` have some prototypes for functions including `Func(param)`. If someone can help me understand a little I will be very thankfull.

---

Yes, the code is for a USB host in a microcontroller I didn't add the code because it could drive the question away, but here it is,

The call is:

```
void USBHOST_Process(USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev , USBH_HOST *phost){
    ...
    if (phost->usr_cb->UserInput() == USBH_USR_RESP_OK){
    ...
    }
    ...
}


typedef struct _Host_TypeDef
{
  HOST_State            gState;       /*  Host State Machine Value */
  HOST_State            gStateBkp;    /* backup of previous State machine value */
  ENUM_State            EnumState;    /* Enumeration state Machine */
  CMD_State             RequestState;       
  USBH_Ctrl_TypeDef     Control;

  USBH_Device_TypeDef   device_prop; 

  USBH_Class_cb_TypeDef               *class_cb;  
  USBH_Usr_cb_TypeDef                 *usr_cb;


} USBH_HOST, *pUSBH_HOST;


typedef struct _USBH_USR_PROP
{
  void (*Init)(void);       /* HostLibInitialized */
  void (*DeInit)(void);       /* HostLibInitialized */  
  void (*DeviceAttached)(void);           /* DeviceAttached */
  void (*ResetDevice)(void);
  void (*DeviceDisconnected)(void); 
  void (*OverCurrentDetected)(void);  
  void (*DeviceSpeedDetected)(uint8_t DeviceSpeed);          /* DeviceSpeed */
  void (*DeviceDescAvailable)(void *);    /* DeviceDescriptor is available */
  void (*DeviceAddressAssigned)(void);  /* Address is assigned to USB Device */
  void (*ConfigurationDescAvailable)(USBH_CfgDesc_TypeDef *,
                                     USBH_InterfaceDesc_TypeDef *,
                                     USBH_EpDesc_TypeDef *); 
  /* Configuration Descriptor available */
  void (*ManufacturerString)(void *);     /* ManufacturerString*/
  void (*ProductString)(void *);          /* ProductString*/
  void (*SerialNumString)(void *);        /* SerialNubString*/
  void (*EnumerationDone)(void);           /* Enumeration finished */
  USBH_USR_Status (*UserInput)(void);
  int  (*UserApplication) (void);
  void (*DeviceNotSupported)(void); /* Device is not supported*/
  void (*UnrecoveredError)(void);

}
USBH_Usr_cb_TypeDef;
```

Now I understand what it does, but I can't find the definition of UserInput(void) I can't find what it does.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c

Comment: Show the code you have questions about, don't try to describe it in prose.

Comment: I don't think that this question should be closed as too localized: the syntax of calling functions through a function pointer embedded in a `struct` is genuinely confusing, especially if you are familiar with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "some prototypes for functions including `Func(param)`" is a [*function pointer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer#Example_in_C). You can invoke a function pointed to by the pointer as if the pointer represented that function's name. The inner-most structure has been set up with a pointer to some function; your code snippet invokes that function through its pointer.

Here is a short example that illustrates how this works ([also on ideone](http://ideone.com/unbrOx)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    void (*func)(int);  
} with_fp;

void test(int n) {
    printf("Test %d\n", n);
}

int main(void) {
    with_fp s = {.func = test};
    with_fp *ptr = &s;
    ptr->func(123);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for downvoting this answer?

Answer (score 1):

It calls the function `Func()` of the structure `struct2` with those parameters.

The function `Func()` is a pointer to a function, a pointer (a memory address) where the instructions which make up the function start.

See [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) for explanations.

The pointer, being a variable, has to be set prior to being used for the call.

Comment: "member function"? This is tagged 'C'.

Comment: I know. It's analogous to "member variable", it's not a member function though as you know it from C++, but it makes it easier for him to grasp the concept.

Comment: @H2CO3 every other question about C++ is tagged 'c'.

Comment: @H2CO3 If a C++ question is tagged 'c', edit it and re-tag, don't treat it as if it was about C. In this case it's not clear what the question is about as we don't see the code.

Comment: @n.m. from the text of the question, it cannot be decided if it's about C or C++ - both languages have the same syntax for two different tasks. So I assumed the question wasn't mistagged, that's why I think the 'member function' terminology is inaccurate.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah, that's why I've removed it. So why still the debate?

Comment: @Flavius One, I didn't notice the edit, sorry. Two, n.m. didn't fully get what I meant, so I wanted to explain my argument more clearly.