# UIBezier path not responding to stroke

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath, quartz-core

I am using the following code to draw a `UIBezierPath` on a `UIImageView` in a `UIView`.
But it is not showing a green path.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [aPath strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    self->aPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];

    CAShapeLayer* greenPath = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    greenPath.path = aPath.CGPath;
    [greenPath setFillColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
    [greenPath setStrokeColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    greenPath.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,100,30);

    //add shape layer to view's layer
    [[imgView layer] addSublayer:greenPath];

    aPath.lineCapStyle=kCGLineCapRound;
    aPath.miterLimit=0;
    aPath.lineWidth=10;

    [aPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:imgView]];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:imgView]];
    [imgView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I need to show a green line wherever the `UIBezierPath` is drawn.

Comment: Do you get the black line? Update the path of the shape layer when you change the bezier path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of weird stuff going on in your code, but it runs, the problem is here

```
[imgView setNeedsDisplay];
```

As I see in your code, you want it to work on `drawRect`, but `drawRect` will only get called on `setNeedsDisplay` on the **current view**, not on `imgView`, switch it for

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

And it will work. You'd probably need to subclass UIImageView to handle drawRect inside of it. Also, I'm guessing that you want to actually modify the image, hence the attempt to draw within in, try reading on working with CoreGraphics in an **image context**.

### About the other issues

The main problem as I see it, is that you're confusing CALayers and CoreGraphics, as it stands right now, the CALayer you're adding to the imageView is completely unused. Just with the `drawRect` and setting the BezierPath as you move around should work.

Also, be careful when using `->`, [understand what you're getting yourself into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c), I usually suggest sticking to `@property`, and using `self.myVar` and `_myVar`.

Comment: Thanks, But this does not work either. I know i have lots of weird stuff going on in my code, because i have to do quite a few different things. Can you just edit the code and repost the correct format?

Comment: @ScarletWitch I could, but that would be kinda against the rules, as it would render your question invalid. Also, the idea is that you learn :)

Comment: [Here's](http://pastebin.com/eWuCJUaM) how your code would look like. I would also swap touch delegates for `UIPanGesutreRecognizer`, but that's just personal preference.