# What does "->" mean in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Well, I'm sorry I can't find any useful results when I search "->" on Google, and this is the first time I've seen anything like this. I've found the following line in one of Ray Wenderlich's game center tutorials:

```
Message *message = (Message *)[data bytes];
if (message->messageType == kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
    ...
}
```

Message here is a predefined struct:

```
typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;
```

From http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-22.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can read more about this sort of syntax? Thanks!

Comment: probably here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B .

Comment: Pretty much exactly the same thing it means in C or C++, which you should know before you attempt to program in Objective-C.

Comment: Well, I self-taught. There are things I don't know. Why are you guys just down voting because I want to know something I can't get from google?

Comment: You should know how to program simple C before you attempt to deal with Objective-C.  You apparently don't even know what a pointer is, which bodes ill for your future efforts.

Comment: @Roma-MT - They are *not* the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the same thing as it does in C and C++, basically you are ***accessing the data of a pointer***.

**If you were using an object:** you might say `message.messageType`

**Since you are dealing with a pointer:** you use `message->messageType` to get the messageType data from the pointer message

This syntax saves you from having to dereference a variable before you access its data.

Here is a link to another StackOverFlow question which was asked from a programmer learning C. The same content/principles apply here. [Arrow Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Here is another link explaining the [Difference Between . and ->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

Comment: ... so the number one use for `->` nowadays is probably accessing unexposed member variables on a variant of `self` that has been deliberately kept weak and then made strong again for the benefit of an asynchronous block.