# What is the difference between -> and dot

Tags: c, ansi-c

In a C program, when i define a struct.

under which circumstances would i use "->" and under which "." ?

for example

```
typedef struct foo foo;

struct foo{

  double bar;
  double bar2;
}

foo barbar;
```

when would I use `barbar.bar` and when would i use `barbar->bar` ?

Comment: This is a much-too-basic C question. Please consult your local C reference book.

Comment: `->` for pointers, `.` for instances. Also, as Daniel pointed out, basic C pointer question. Should be found in any good book or tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Comment: `a->b` is *exactly the same* as `(*a).b`, so the answer is: you would use `->` any time you would use `(*a).b`.  If you don't understand what `*a` means then you need to go back a step and learn about the fundamental relationships between *storage* and *pointers*.  `&` turns *storage* into a *pointer*, and `*` turns a *pointer* back into *storage*. Make sure you understand this at a deep level before you continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left of `->` should be pointer type, while normal variables/instances for `.`.

- If you have a `struct foo myFoo`, you should use `myFoo.` or `(&myFoo)->`.
- If you have a `struct foo *myFoo`, you should use `myFoo->` or `(*myFoo).`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `->` for a pointer to a struct as it dereferences the pointer, use a `.` for a struct