# What does the -> operator do in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Sorry if this question has been asked before but there were literally no results when i typed it into google. As the title states, I would like to know what the `->` operator does. I see it everywhere: `[self processTorrent:alert->handle];` but don't know what it does

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c

Answer (score 0):

It's the structure dereference ("member b of object pointed to by a") in C. Objective-C is a strict superset of C.

The the usual way to access a member a is as s.a which, given the pointer, is expressed as (*p).a or can instead be accessed by the shorthand:

p->a  using the structure dereference operator.

```
struct point
{
    int* x;
    int* y;
};

structure point* struct1;
```

As with any pointer. To change the address it points to:

```
struct1->x = &varX;
```

To change the value at the address to which it points:

```
*(struct1->x) = varX;
```

Comment: Why would `x` and `y` be pointers? That's confusing the answer since it's not relevant to the question.