# Refreshing pointer with integer and character

Tags: c, pointers, integer, character, structure

i am not getting output for this program. 
// Pointer and structure
I want get output as 1Jatin. but for refreshing pointer by using structure. i cant do that. It working as int and float. but not as int and char. any one please solved out this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct name{
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main(){
    struct name *ptr ,p;
    ptr = &p;
    printf("Enter integer:");
    scanf("%d", &(*ptr).a);
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", &(*ptr).b);
    printf("Displaying:");
    printf("%d%s",(*ptr).a,(*ptr).b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 32

struct name{
    int a;
    char b[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
};

int main(){
    struct name *ptr ,p;
    ptr = &p;
    printf("Enter integer:");
    scanf("%d", &ptr->a);
    printf("Enter name:");
    scanf("%s", ptr->b);
    printf("Displaying: ");
    printf("%d %s\n",ptr->a,ptr->b);

    return 0;
}
```

Many things:

1. You can simply us [`->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575050/3436922) to dereference pointer to its members
2. C-Strings are null terminated arrays of chars. That means that `b` member must be an array large enough to store a name characters + null terminator (`'\0'`, `0x00`, `0`).