# error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct xmplrpc_binding’)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I got the error message:

```
../usr/examples/xmpl-rpc/rpc_rpc.c: In function ‘send_myrpc’:
../usr/examples/xmpl-rpc/rpc_rpc.c:40:25: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct xmplrpc_binding’)
 err = xmplrpc_client->rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc(&xmplrpc_client, in, &s_out);
                     ^
```

and the definition of `xmplrpc_client` is:

```
static struct xmplrpc_binding xmplrpc_client;
```

The struct `xmplrpc_binding` has

```
struct xmplrpc_rpc_tx_vtbl rpc_tx_vtbl;
```

And the struct `xmplrpc_rpc_tx_vtbl` is

```
struct xmplrpc_rpc_tx_vtbl {
  xmplrpc_myrpc__rpc_tx_method_fn *myrpc;
};
```

It's obvious that `xmplrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc` is the wrong way, and I think the way I wrote `xmplrpc_client->rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc` is correct.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: xmplrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl->myrpc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `->` operator when the operand (which appears to the *left* of the operator) is a pointer to a `struct` or `union` type, and `.` when the operand is an *instance* of a `struct` or `union` type.

So...

`xmplrpc_client` is declared as an *instance* of `struct xmplrpc_binding`, thus you would use the `.` operator to access any of it's members:

```
xmlrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl
```

The member `rpc_tx_vtbl` is declared as an *instance* of `struct mplrpc_rpc_tx_vtbl`, so again, you'd use the `.` operator to access any of its members:

```
xmlrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc
```

Thus, your call should be written

```
err = xmplrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc(&xmplrpc_client, in, &s_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the error you should write it this way

```
 xmplrpc_client.rpc_tx_vtbl.myrpc(/* and args */);
```

this my solve the confusion [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Comment: The `->` wouldn't be used at all - neither `xmlrpc_client` nor `rpc_tx_vtbl` are pointers to `struct`.

Comment: @JohnBode oh yeah just noticed! Thanks