# C++ operator -> in complex numbers case

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

The problem is to implement class `Cplx` with two doubles `x` and `y` represent real and imaginary part of complex numbers.
One of the subtask is to implement `operator ->` with following description:

(`z­->re` and `z­->im`): access to the real and imaginary part of `z`(You must implement changing like `z->re = 5`).

I have troubles with `operator ->` I never really understand how it works so my question is: how `->` works and when to use it and how to apply that idea in this problem.

Comment: Wasn't the *pointer to member* operator covered in the lectures?

Comment: If you really must name the doubles `x` and `y` implementing the behaviour `z->re` would be rather complicated. (Or I misunderstand the task description, it’s hard to follow, to be honest.)

Comment: @idmean: Not so complicated, but very strange.

Comment: [Arrow operator (->) usage in C&C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does what you ask... But not sure it is what you want:

```
template <typename T>
struct ReIm
{
    const ReIm* operator ->() const { return this; }
    ReIm* operator ->() { return this; }

    T re;
    T im;
};


struct Cplx
{
    double x;
    double y;

    ReIm<double> operator ->() const { return {x, y}; }
    ReIm<double&> operator ->() { return {x, y}; }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/DNXrAS)

Comment: nice. way to go.

Comment: That’s what I had in mind, and to me it seems overly complicated in contrast to its benefit. On the other hand, it’s probably just an exercise.

Comment: I think it's more likely the OP misunderstood or failed the present their task properly. But it's always neat to see how even the most obscure requirement can sometimes be done in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The -> operator works to dereference a pointer to an object and get a member variable/function in one operator. For example,

```
Cplx* cplxPointer = new Cplx();
cplxPointer->x = 5;
```

Is the same as

```
Cplx* cplxPointer = new Cplx();
(*cplxPointer).x = 5;
```

It just dereferences the pointer and then gets the member variable (or function if you want). Unless I misunderstood your question, the above should be able to help you complete your assignment.