# Can I use . as member qualifier in gnu c structures

Tags: c, arm, bare-metal

Is it ok to use . as a member qualifier instead of the symbol -> for structures in GNU c. The compiler does not complain when symbol . used in place of ->.

Comment: Please show some code, your terminology usage is non-standard.

Comment: `.` is used to access members of a structure; `->` is used to access members of a structure pointed to. The latter dereferences the pointer and then gets the member. So `p->x` is equivalent to `(*p).x`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is used to access members of a structure; `->` is used to access members of a structure pointed to. The latter dereferences the pointer and then gets the member. So `p->x` is equivalent to `(*p).x`. Example:

```
struct P {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct P myP = {1,2};
struct P *p= &myP;

printf("%d, %d\n", myP.x, myP.y);   // prints 1, 2
printf("%d, %d\n", p->x, p->y);     // prints the same
printf("%d, %d\n", (*p).x, (*p).y); // is the same
```