# How can *ptr be used with (.) and (&test) can be used with -> in following code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have written following program .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Test
{
   int count;
};

void main()
{
   struct Test *ptr;
   struct Test test;

   ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
   if ( ptr)
   {
      ptr->count = 123;
      test.count  = 456;

      printf("count : %d ",(*ptr).count);
      printf("count : %d ",(&test)->count);
   }
   else
   {
      printf(" malloc failed \n");
   }
}
```

output of the program: 
count : 123 
count : 456

Can anyone please explain how to represent **(*ptr).coun**t and **(&test)->count** in this code and how it is working ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to represent .. and .. in my code'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ptr` and `test` are 2 vars of different types. `ptr` is a pointer to `struct Test`, whereas `test` just *is* that struct. As per usual, you access values of pointers through indirection (denoted by `->` as opposed to `.`).

To reassign a pointer, first you have to *dereference* the pointer, which is done using the `*` operator, hence: `(*ptr).count` is basically read as: *get the value `ptr` points to and use it*. The entire expression is basically the long-form of `ptr->count`.

`(&test)->count` on the other hand is a bit silly. You have an object on stack, but rather than accessing its fields quickly and cheaply, you are getting the memory address (which is what `&` does - it's the *"address of"* operator), and creating an in-place pointer. Then you are getting the value stored in `count` using indirection. The expression `(&test)->count` reads as: *"get me a pointer to `test`, and using that pointer, access the field `count`"*. It's equivalent to `*(&test).count` A bit redundant, then.

Answer (score 1):

`(&test)->count` is equivalent to `(*(&test)).count`. For more, you can glance at [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `a->x` is basically short for `(*a).x`, it's just that working with pointers to structures is quite common in C, so the syntax has some extra sugar there to make it simpler. Dropping the need for parentheses is really helpful in my opinion.

Basically you use `.` when the value on the left-hand side is of `struct` type, and `->` when it is the address of a structure.