# printing struct member using user input

Tags: c

So I've been looking at structures, functions and pointers for days now. I just cant wrap my head around structures good enough to do what I want...

I was trying to write a function, which was originally going to receive user input (taken with fgets) as an argument. I have put that aside now, and just decided to give the function a single argument. That argument will be the name of a struct, and I'll use that name to access it's variables and print them the way I want.

```
typedef struct
{
 int hp;
 char *name;
} bare;
bare example;
void print_info(char *name);
int main()
{
 example.hp = 5;
 strcpy(example.name,"John");
 print_info("example");
}
void print_info(char *name)
{
 printf("The hp of %s is %d", (*name), (*name)->hp);
}
```

Whatever bloody thing I put there instead of char *name, it always ended up giving me the error "error: struct or union expected"! I tried struct bare **name and (*name)->hp/(*name).hp, char *name/**name and *&name.hp, *&name->hp, every possible solution I could think of..! i think they all turned out to be nonsense... I just cant wrap my head around pointers and structs enough to do this! A little help please? I searched high and low on function arguments, pointers and structs, yet couldn't find a solution/question like mine..

Comment: A pointer variable will point to the memory that you want to use to store the name. An array is the memory that can be used to store the name.

Comment: The only way to refer to an object from a string is to look up the object from some association table. If you export your symbols from translation unit so that it is findable by a linked library, you can do the lookup using dlsym. Otherwise, you have to create the lookup data structure yourself. That data structure would allow you to associate a string to a `bare *`.

Comment: So, your `print_info` function would need to lookup the `bare *`, and then you can use `->` on the `bare *`.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, it's better to declare your struct this way:

```c
typedef struct bare {
    int hp;
    char *name;
} bare;
```

**Second**, avoid global variable as much as you can. I don't see the point of declaring `example` in the global namespace since you are using it only inside `main()`.

**Third**, this line has a problem:

```c
strcpy(example.name, "John");
```

You are attempting to copy `"John"` to an uninitialized pointer (`example.name`) that points to some random memory address. You have to either allocate enough space using `malloc()` (and free it when you're done with it), or use a fixed-length array. Moreover, it's better to use `strncpy()` because it allows to specify the maximum number of characters to copy. This way you avoid the risk of buffer overflow.

**Fourth**, to avoid copying your entire struct to `print_info()` (in fact, any other struct to any other function), you should pass its address.

With all that said, here is how your code should be written:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct bare {
    int hp;
    char name[100]; // Make sure it has enough space, or use malloc() if you don't know how much it will hold initially
} bare;

void print_info(bare *name);

int main(void)
{
    bare example; // Declare it inside main()
    example.hp = 5;
    
    strncpy(example.name, "John", sizeof example.name); // This works and is safe
    
    print_info(&example);
}

void print_info(bare *name)
{
    printf("The hp of %s is %d", name->name, name->hp);
}
```

Output:

```text
The hp of John is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wish to do is this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    int hp;
    char *name;
} bare;
bare example;
void print_info(bare *name);
int main() {
    example.hp = 5;
    strcpy(example.name, "John");
    print_info(&example);
}
void print_info(bare *name) {
    printf("The hp of %s is %d", name->name, name->hp);
}
```

Or if you want to pass `example` by value:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    int hp;
    char *name;
} bare;
bare example;
void print_info(bare name);
int main() {
    example.hp = 5;
    strcpy(example.name, "John");
    print_info(example);
}
void print_info(bare name) {
    printf("The hp of %s is %d", name.name, name.hp);
}
```

### Why did your code not work?

1. `print_info` had an incorrect argument data type. What you wanted was to pass an object of `bare` or perhaps a pointer to an object of `bare`, but you were instead passing a variable of type `char *`.
2. The arrow operator is used on pointers. Maybe take a look at [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

#### You wanted to pass in a string typed in by the user.

> I was trying to write a function, which was originally going to receive user input (taken with `fgets`) as an argument. I have put that aside now, and just decided to give the function a single argument.

This explains why you pass in a `char *` to your function. The input value was originally going to be read from `fgets`. In your program, you passed in the name of your variable.

```
bare example;
/* ... */
 print_info("example");
```

#### To do a dynamic lookup on a symbol name, use `dlsym`.

As I suggested in comments, if you want to be able to look up the name of a variable to find the associated object, you can use `dlsym` so long as you are on a POSIX system (like Linux). For example:

```
// Need to inlcude <dlfcn.h> and link with -ldl
// Make local variables findable with -rdynamic
void print_info(char *name)
{
 bare *p = dlsym(0, name);
 if (p != NULL)
  printf("The hp of %s is %d", p->name, p->hp);
 else
  printf("%s not found!\n", name);
}
```

So long as you include `<dlfcn.h>` and use `-ldl` when linking the program, and you make your symbol table visible (with `-rdynamic` on GCC), the program will find the pointer to your `example` variable. ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NTsQgFEb3PMUdzCR00k5mM6vOzAOYiStdqTHITyGhQFpqbExfXYRaTd24IfDlnu9cWNUwFuONtswMXMCpD1y7vbqgddRp2/zNuJHM5giF0QsuJKSpgQX0gUDbAMrXCJiiHVjaisfj4blGE7zSTtQonyDeaetNer05zcEnQ3jRVjoyQ7tMFTXKVS3VlhS5eGH2ysMZjkmQnMyP5CfPUIlvnbI4setSvIzkfPpPmTXzfrvs4KYfW3IoYVkHtATiYXOGu4frtUDw3SIJvlci/RmchG0PuoctxyX46jKvlC/KZ16YXqyoNGtdAOkGyzdPFv@Kphg/mTS06WPV8TGlmsXKcPMF))

#### But you probably meant to do a lookup by `name`.

However, you seemed to have mixed some things up. Usually, the user will not care what names you have used for the variables in your program. You would never expect `fgets` to give you `"example"` because that is not what the user would type in.

You probably meant to search for the `bare` record that matches the name parameter of `bare`. In your case, `"John"`.

```
 print_info("John");
```

Normally, you would have a table of `bare`s that you would look over and check for a match. However, in your simplified example, there is only one to check.

```
bare * find_bare(char *name)
{
 if (strcmp(name, example.name) == 0) return &example;
 return NULL;
}

void print_info(char *name)
{
 bare *p = find_bare(name);
 if (p != NULL)
  printf("The hp of %s is %d", p->name, p->hp);
 else
  printf("%s not found!\n", name);
}
```

#### It isn't hard to create and search a table of `bare`.

In this case, you could probably simple create an array of `bare` to represent your collection that you would search over.

```
#define BARE_TABLE_SIZE 50
bare table_example[BARE_TABLE_SIZE];
```

Assuming you add the code to populate your table, you could use a simple loop to search for a matching name.

```
bare * find_bare(char *name)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < BARE_TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
 {
  if (strcmp(name, table_example[i].name) == 0)
   return &table_example[i];
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

#### Your `example.name` was an uninitialized pointer.

Finally, the most egregious error in your program is the attempt to call `strcpy` on an uninitialized pointer. One solution is to allocate new memory to hold the new name and assign the location of the new name to the pointer. POSIX systems (like Linux) supply a function called `strdup` that creates a copy of the input for you, in newly allocated memory.

```
 example.name = strdup("John");
```

Since the memory is allocated by `malloc`, you would need to call `free` on the pointer if `example` is ever recycled for a new name.

Comment: Yes thank you! I came from C# and a bit of Python, I'm really not used to compiler options, linking, allocating memory for variables and whatnot (couldnt compile your code). I wanted to take the string, (optionally look if it matches any struct variables first) refer to a struct and print a member of that struct! You did what I wanted to.. sort of, just not as flexible as I wanted it to be, I have lots of structs in my project, so I wanted to search every single one under bare and look for a match.. If I do ```example.name;```first,then assign something to it, do I still need to use malloc() ?

Comment: Coming from C#, you may get closer to the coding style you are used to if you use C++ rather than C.

Comment: If you do not want to deal with `malloc` and `free` of the name, define it as an array, as suggested in the other answers.