# I am having trouble understanding the -> operator in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, append, nodes

The image below is my instructor's code on how to append a node to a linked list. I understand that the tail pointer is used to traverse through the list until it reaches a node with link containing `NULL`. However, I do not understand how `tail = tail->next` traverses through the list?

[image: Append Node To List]

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c

Comment: "`->` operator in C" has been covered many times on stackoverflow

Comment: If you have an instructor, why don't you ask them? Their job is to teach the language.

Comment: `tail` is a pointer to the current node. `tail->next` is the value of the `next` member in the node that `tail` points to. So if you reassign to that value, it traverses to the next node in the list. Do it repeatedly traverses until you reach the end.

Comment: `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`.  I.e. `a` is a pointer to a `struct` or `union`, and `b` is the member you wish to access.  It's an example of what's called "syntactic sugar".  Similarly, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow operator (->) usage in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575048/arrow-operator-usage-in-c)

Comment: @Barmar but how does reassigning by tail = tail->next traverse to the next node. From my understanding, that line would just make tail be equal to whatever it's pointing to so it would be an endless loop.

Comment: `tail` is first pointing to a node. Then it gets the `next` pointer from that node, and assigns that to `tail`. So now it's pointing to the node after it.

Comment: Why do you think it makes it equal to whatever it's pointing to? That would be `tail = tail`.

Comment: Put `printf("tail = %p tail.next = %p\n", tail, tail.next);` before and after the assignment, and you'll see what it's doing.

Comment: It's similar to the way `n = n + 1` is how you would traverse through sequential numbers.

Comment: @Barmar in the struct node definition o : struct node { int value; struct node* next; } or the main program, there is no line that suggests next is pointing to the link (next) on another node, so it seems as if tail = (tail*).next just keeps assigning to itself. Sorry if that does not make sense I'm just really confused about this.

Comment: `next` points to the next node, not the tail of the next node. But after you do `tail = tail->next`, now `tail` points to the next node. And you repeat this each time.

Comment: @Barmar how do we know that next is pointing to another node?

Comment: Because its type is `struct node*`. So it can't point to anything other than another node. And the code that adds nodes to the list uses this to create the list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at this in memory. Suppose you have 3 nodes, at addresses `10`, `20`, `30`, and `head` points to the node at address `10`. You'll have the following memory contents:

```
10: value = 1
    next = 20
20: value = 2
    next = 30
30: value = 3
    next = NULL
head = 10
```

After you do `tail = head`, we also have:

```
tail = 10
```

Now we do `tail = tail->next;`. `tail->next` dereferences `tail` to get the structure at address `10`, then fetches the value from its `next` member, which is `20`. After the assignment, we now have:

```
tail = 20
```

So this has stepped `tail` to the next node in the list.

The next time through the loop, we do it again. `tail->next` fetches the `next` member in the structure at location `20`, which is `30`, so we'll now have:

```
tail = 30
```

The loop now stops, because with this value of `tail`, `tail->next` contains `NULL`, so the condition `while (tail->next != NULL)` fails.

Comment: thank you so much for a detailed explanation, this made so much sense!