# difference between -> and . for member selection operator

Tags: c++, class, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between (.) dot operator and (->) arrow in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-operator-and-arrow-in-c)

in this book i have I'm learning pointers, and i just got done with the chapter about OOP (spits on ground) anyways its telling me i can use a member selection operator like this ( -> ). it sayd that is is like the "." except points to objects rather than member objects. whats the difference, it looks like it is used the same way...

Comment: Duplicate of [what is the difference between (.) dot operator and (->) arrow in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-operator-and-arrow-in-c) (and others)

Comment: If E1 has the type “pointer to class X,” then the expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`. In other words, `->` is just a shortcut for "dereference-and-access".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, it actually does the same thing but for different kind of variables.

If you have a pointer you have to use `->`, while if you have a real value you will use `.`.

So for example

```
struct mystruct *pointer;
struct mystruct var;

pointer->field = ...
var.field = ...
```

That's not hard at all. Just remember that with a pointer you will need `->`, and `.` otherwise.

Comment: thank you very much. i thought so but my mind is pudding right now. so if the line has a pointer in it use -> or else use a .

Answer (score 8):

Where:

```
Foo foo;
Foo* pfoo = &foo;
```

`pfoo->mem` is semantically identical to `(*pfoo).mem`.

Or, put another way: `foo.mem` is semantically identical to `(&foo)->mem`.

Comment: It's semantically identical. It would be syntactically identical if it was the same sequence of tokens :)

Comment: `foo.mem` === `(*(&foo)).mem` :-)

Comment: This is indirectly confusing since some of the foos in your examples are pointers and others are objects.

Comment: Did I fix all of the pedantic boo-boos?

Comment: Not quite: `operator->` and unary `operator*` and `operator&` can be overloaded, but `operator.` can't. So your equivalences are necessarily true only when `pfoo` is a pointer. Other types that support your stated expressions may or may not implement the operators to be equivalent. You did ask ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Fair enough. I'm aware of this, but for the purposes of the question, my answer seems good enough.

Comment: I agree the answer is good enough :-) Just that for pedantry, you could state the types of `foo` and `pfoo`. It's reasonable given the question that `pfoo` is of type `decltype(foo) *`, though, and overloading `operator&` breaks 99% of generic code anyway...

Answer (score 5):

You only use -> when the variable is a **pointer** to your object:

```
A* a = new A;
a->member();
```

Use "." when it's not a pointer:

```
A a;
a.member();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct S
{
    int a, b;
};

S st;
S* pst = &st;
st.a = 1;    // . takes an object (or reference to one)
pst->b = 2;  // -> takes a pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an object instance (`MyObject object;`), you use the `.` to access it members (methods, properties, fields, etc), like this: `object.Member`.

When you have a pointer to an object instance (`MyObject* pObject = new MyObject();`), you need to dereference the pointer, before you can access the object members. To dereference a pointer you use the `*` operator. Thus, when you combine both, you get something like this: `(*pObject).Member`.

Of course, this is not readable, so the compilers take the `->` as a shorthand for it. Thus, it becomes `pObject->Member`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example will help

```
object o;
object *p = &o;  // pointer to object
o.member;   // access member
p->member;  // access member through pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `->` to dereference the pointer, when you access members via pointer, you use `.` when you access directly on member.

```
class A
{
   public:
   int x;
   void g() {};
};

A a;
a.x
a.g();

A * ap = new A();
ap->x;
ap->g();
```

and you can dereference pointer and then use `.`:

```
(*ap).x;
(*ap).g();
```