# C++ different -> and "."

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between (.) dot operator and (->) arrow in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-operator-and-arrow-in-c)

I'm trying to learn c++, but what I don't understand is the different between "->" and "." when calling a method.

For example, I have seen something like class->method(), and class.method().

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the type of `class` in either case?

Comment: Time to get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a normal case, `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`. If `a` is a pointer, `->` dereferences it before accessing the element.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator calls a method on the object pointed to by a pointer.

The `.` operator calls a method on an object itself.

If `a` is a pointer, `a->b()` is equivalent to `(*a).b()`.

Answer (score 1):

You use -> when the thing on the left is a pointer to an object.  You use '.' when the thing on the left is the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

When your calling a method through a pointer, you use `->`; otherwise, use `.`.

Example:

```
MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
obj->myMethod();

MyClass obj2;
obj2.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a bit irritating at first but C/C++ differenciates calling a method through the use of a pointer (use of `->`) or through the use of a variable/reference (use of `.`). So the type of variable you use decides whether you call with the one or with the other option.

Note that in many other programming languages (Java, C#, ...) this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You will *never* see `class.method()` or `class->method()` in C++. What you will see is `object.method()`, `obj_ptr->method()` or `class::method()`. When you make an object of a class, you use the `.` operator, when refering to a *pointer* to an object, you use `->` and when calling a static method directly without making an object, you use `::`. If you have a class `a_class` like below, then:

```
class a_class
{
   public:
      void a_method()
      {
         std::cout<<"Hello world"<<std::endl;
      }
      static void a_static_method()
      {
         std::cout<<"Goodbye world"<<endl;
      }
}

int main()
{
    a_class a_object = a_class();
    a_class* a_pointer = new a_class();

    a_object.a_method(); //prints "Hello world"
    a_object->a_method(); //error
    a_object::a_method(); //error

    a_pointer.a_method(); //error
    a_pointer->a_method(); //prints "Hello world"
    a_pointer::a_method(); //error

    *a_pointer.a_method(); //prints "Hello world"
    *a_pointer->a_method(); //error
    *a_pointer::a_method(); //error

    a_class.a_method(); //error
    a_class->a_method(); //error
    a_class::a_method(); //error because a_method is not static        

    a_class.a_static_method(); //error
    a_class->a_static_method(); //error
    a_class::a_static_method(); //prints "Goodbye world"

}
```