# Operator '.' vs '->' in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

What is the difference between the two? When do you use one instead of the other?

There was once I tried to use '->' instead of '.' and I got "left operand has 'class' type, use '.'" error, what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` allows you to access members of a class.  `thingy.member`, for example.

If you have a **pointer** to your class, say `pThingy`, you need to dereference it in order to access the members.  Like `(*pthingy).member`.

A shortcut to the dereference/access combination is `->`: `pThingy->member`.

Answer (score 2):

All these answers are somewhat correct in a narrow scope. You can use the -> operator even if you don't have a pointer because you can overload it. Take a look at smart pointers:

```
class A
{
    public:
       void foo();
}

class SmartPtr
{
public:
    SmartPtr (A& obj)
    {
        instance = obj;
    }
    A instance;
    A operator-> ()
    {
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Then you can do:

```
A a;
SmartPtr smart(a);
smart->foo();
```

so you can use -> even though SmartPtr is not a pointer to an object of type SmartPtr.

This answer is in addition to previous ones, as they might be misleading. In a simple case, they are all correct. Note that the dot(.) operator cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

`.` to be use if the object is of type `T`. `->` if the object is of type `T*`.

```
class foo {};

foo obj;
```

`obj` type is `foo` and it lies on stack. So, to access it's members `.` operator needs to be used.

```
foo *hObj = new foo();
```

`hObj` is a pointer to the object. So, to access it's members `->` operator needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You use `object.property` to get the property of an object. However if you have a pointer to an object (let's call it `pointer_to_object`) then you will use `->` to access its properties: `pointer_to_object->property`

The reason why you got the error is because the statement `pointer_to_object->property` will try to dereference first to the actual object and then access its property. If the variable is not a pointer to an object, then you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`x->blah` is a nice why of writing `(*x).blah`. That is it dereferences a pointer, and then accesses the member `blah`. If x isn't a pointer than you have a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

If a is a pointer (or an object proposing "pointer semantics") think to `a->b` as `(*a).b`

In more  general term, if `a` is not a *pointer* they are two operators: `->` is overridable (so what it does depends on the class it applies, note **class** as a type, not *pointer to a class*: see above for that), the other is the non overridable *member selection* (meaningless for non composite types), so 
`a->b` means *"access the b member trough the pointer returned by `A::operator->()` called on `a`"*,
and `a.b` means *"access the `b` member of `a`"*.