# C++ Error: No match for 'operator='

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Having a problem when assigning a value to an array. I have a class I created called `Treasury`. I created another class called `TradingBook` which I want to contain a global array of `Treasury` that can be accessed from all methods in `TradingBook`. Here is my header files for TradingBook and Treasury:

```
class Treasury{
public:
    Treasury(SBB_instrument_fields bond);
    Treasury();
    double yieldRate;
    short periods;
};


class TradingBook
{
public:
    TradingBook(const char* yieldCurvePath, const char* bondPath);
    double getBenchmarkYield(short bPeriods) const;
    void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right, double index[]);

    BaseBond** tradingBook;
    int treasuryCount;
    Treasury* yieldCurve;
    int bondCount;
    void runAnalytics(int i);
};
```

And here is my main code where I'm getting the error:

```
TradingBook::TradingBook(const char* yieldCurvePath, const char* bondPath)
{
    //Loading Yield Curve
    // ...
    yieldCurve = new Treasury[treasuryCount];

    int periods[treasuryCount];
    double yields[treasuryCount];
    for (int i=0; i < treasuryCount; i++)
    {
        yieldCurve[i] = new Treasury(treasuries[i]);
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^LINE WITH ERROR^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> No match for `'operator='` on the line `'yieldCurve[i] = new Treasury(treasuries[i]);'`

Any advice?

Comment: This is the exact same problem you [asked about yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781292/c-when-to-exactly-use-error-base-operand-of-has-non-pointer-type). The only difference is that it's happening with a different variable. Perhaps it's time to invest in a good C++ book, as your understanding of arrays and pointers could use improvement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `yieldCurve[i]` is of type `Treasury`, and `new Treasury(treasuries[i]);` is a pointer to a `Treasury` object. So you have a type mismatch.

Try changing this line:

```
yieldCurve[i] = new Treasury(treasuries[i]);
```

to this:

```
yieldCurve[i] = Treasury(treasuries[i]);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    Treasury* yieldCurve;
```

`yieldCurve` is a pointer to an array of `Treasury`, not `Treasury*`. Drop the `new` at the line with error, or modify the declaration for it to be an array of pointers.