# Compilation error: no match for 'operator--'

Tags: compiler-errors, meta-toolkit

Cannot build meta-toolkit on Windows (Win10 64-bit). I followed the instructions at https://meta-toolkit.org/setup-guide.html#windows-build-guide

```
Scanning dependencies of target feature-summary
[ 59%] Building CXX object src/features/tools/CMakeFiles/feature-summary.dir/feature_summary.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/some/other/path/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/8.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from C:/some/other/path/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/8.2.1/algorithm:61,
                 from C:/some/path/meta-toolkit/meta/deps/cpptoml/include/cpptoml.h:10,
                 from C:/some/path/meta-toolkit/meta/src/features/tools/feature_summary.cpp:10:
...
C:/some/path/meta-toolkit/meta/src/features/tools/feature_summary.cpp:51:61:   required from here
C:/some/other/path/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/8.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:183:2: error: no match for 'operator--' (operand type is 'meta::learn::dataset_view::iterator')
  --__i;
  ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/features/tools/CMakeFiles/feature-summary.dir/build.make:63: src/features/tools/CMakeFiles/feature-summary.dir/feature_summary.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1406: src/features/tools/CMakeFiles/feature-summary.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

A quick search for this error message seems to imply that (elsewhere, in unrelated code) there is a pointer-vs-object mismatch [C++ Error: No match for 'operator='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788612/c-error-no-match-for-operator)

Comment: I have the exact same error. Any solutions?

Comment: @LoukitKhemka Cross-posted to the meta-toolkit forum, maybe some answers can come from there https://forum.meta-toolkit.org/t/make-error-in-win-10-error-no-match-for-operator/442

Comment: I did do that before I can here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `"--__i"` with `"__i = __i -1"`
in file `C:\some\path\msys64\mingw64\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\stl_iterator_base_funcs.h`, line 183.

This worked for me! :)

Comment: mention file name to edit
~/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/8.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h (line#183)