# What is the difference between "::" "." and "->" in c++

Tags: c++, operators, field, member

I created a class called *`Kwadrat`*. The class has three `int` fields. My *Development Environment* suggests that I access the fields from *`Kwadrat`* created objects via the **`::`** & **`->`** operators. I tried both operators, and found that the **`->`** operator is able to successfully access the data in the objects fields, although, the same cannot be said for the **`->`** operator.
I have also found that the **`.`** operator will access class members as well. I am confused, and don't understand why there are three members for accessing object members &/or methods. Can someone please explain to me what the difference is between the three operators?

---

## 1. `->`

## 2. `::`

## 3. `.`

---

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Kwadrat{

    public: 
        int val1,
            val2,
            val3;

        Kwadrat(int val1, int val2, int val3)
        {
            this->val1 = val1; // Working
            this.val2 = val2;  // Doesn't Work!
            this::val3 = val3; // Doesn't Work!
        }
    };


    int main()
    {
        Kwadrat* kwadrat = new Kwadrat(1,2,3);

        cout<<kwadrat->val1<<endl;
        cout<<kwadrat->val2<<endl;
        cout<<kwadrat->val3<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c/1238639#1238639

Answer (score 182, accepted):

1.`->` for accessing object member variables and methods via `pointer` to object

```
Foo *foo = new Foo();
foo->member_var = 10;
foo->member_func();
```

2.`.`  for accessing object member variables and methods via object `instance`

```
Foo foo;
foo.member_var = 10;
foo.member_func();
```

3.`::` for accessing static variables and methods of a `class/struct` or `namespace`. It can also be used to access variables and functions from another scope (actually class, struct, namespace are scopes in that case)

```
int some_val = Foo::static_var;
Foo::static_method();
int max_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Comment: @ltjax: References are accessed like normal variables. You can do `ref = 2;` or `ref.x = 5;` for an object instance.

Comment: I know, I was just dropping a hint that you might want to add it to 2.

Comment: You can have a reference to any of them. A reference always keep the same type. It's actually a different subject.

Comment: You can not have references to classes/namespaces. For pointers, there's no semantic difference when accessing them; but there is a difference between MyType(myRef).foo() and myRef.foo(). Hence I thought it might be a good idea to explicitly add it for 2. Your choice though.

Comment: @ltjax: the rule for the references is the same as for objects they are refering to. For example if you make a reference to pointer you will use `->` and if to instance - `.`. So I agree with Alex and don't think that it's belongs to 2.

Comment: The list is not comprehensive, nor 100% correct. The *scope operator* can be used in more situations to qualify an entity, even when they are not static: `void derived::f() { base::f(); }` even combined with any of the other two: `obj.base::f()`, and the *access operator* can be used to access statics: `struct test { static const int i = 1; }; test t; int j = t.i;`...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: agree with scope operator. But I prefere not to access static vars/funcs via access operator

Comment: @Andrew: Our particular preferences are unrelated to the operators. There are many things I don't like in the language, but they are still there...

Comment: I would add a blurb that pointer->doSomething() performs an inline dereference and is really the same as (&pointer).doSomething(); and is merely syntactic sugar

Answer (score 31):

In C++ you can access fields or methods, using different operators, depending on it's type:

- **ClassName::FieldName** : class public static field and methods
- **ClassInstance.FieldName** : accessing a public field (or method) through class reference
- **ClassPointer->FieldName** : accessing a public field (or method) dereferencing a class pointer

Note that :: should be used with a class name rather than a class instance, since static fields or methods are common to all instances of a class.

```
class AClass{
public:
static int static_field;
int instance_field;

static void static_method();
void method();
};
```

then you access this way:

```
AClass instance;
AClass *pointer = new AClass();

instance.instance_field; //access instance_field through a reference to AClass
instance.method();

pointer->instance_field; //access instance_field through a pointer to AClass
pointer->method();

AClass::static_field;  
AClass::static_method();
```

Comment: But I canąt get access through
        AClass::static_field = 0;

Comment: i like the unicode character in your comment, @Yoda :)

Answer (score 19):

Put very simple `::` is the scoping operator, `.` is the access operator (I forget what the actual name is?), and `->` is the dereference arrow.

`::` - Scopes a function. That is, it lets the compiler know what class the function lives in and, thus, how to call it. If you are using this operator to call a function, the function is a `static` function.

`.` - This allows access to a member function on an already created object. For instance, `Foo x; x.bar()` calls the method `bar()` on instantiated object `x` which has type `Foo`. You can also use this to access public class variables.

`->` - Essentially the same thing as `.` except this works on pointer types. In essence it dereferences the pointer, than calls `.`. Using this is equivalent to `(*ptr).method()`

Comment: I think the . operator is literally called the "dot operator"

Answer (score 8):

You have a pointer to an object. Therefore, you need to access a field of an object that's pointed to by the pointer. To dereference the pointer you use `*`, and to access a field, you use `.`, so you can use:

```
cout << (*kwadrat).val1;
```

Note that the parentheses are necessary. This operation is common enough that long ago (when C was young) they decided to create a "shorthand" method of doing it:

```
cout << kwadrat->val1;
```

These are defined to be identical. As you can see, the `->` basically just combines a `*` and a `.` into a single operation. If you were dealing directly with an object or a reference to an object, you'd be able to use the `.` without dereferencing a pointer first:

```
Kwadrat kwadrat2(2,3,4);

cout << kwadrat2.val1;
```

The `::` is the scope resolution operator. It is used when you only need to qualify the *name*, but you're not dealing with an individual object at all. This would be primarily to access a static data member:

```
struct something { 
    static int x; // this only declares `something::x`. Often found in a header
};

int something::x;  // this defines `something::x`. Usually in .cpp/.cc/.C file.
```

In this case, since `x` is `static`, it's not associated with any particular instance of `something`. In fact, it will exist even if no instance of that type of object has been created. In this case, we can access it with the scope resolution operator:

```
something::x = 10;

std::cout << something::x;
```

Note, however, that it's also permitted to access a static member as if it was a member of a particular object:

```
something s;

s.x = 1;
```

At least if memory serves, early in the history of C++ this wasn't allowed, but the meaning is unambiguous, so they decided to allow it.

Comment: You helped me a lot but i don't understand why this does not work

 class Something{
        public:
            static int i;
    };
    Something::i = 0;
    cout<<Something::i<<endl;

Comment: @RobertKilar: That declares but does not *define* `Something::i;`, so you need a separate definition of it, like `int Something::i;`, as I show in the code sample in the answer. Otherwise, the code will compile but not link, because `Something::i` will be an "unresolved external/undefined reference".

Answer (score 7):

The three operators have related but different meanings, despite the misleading note from the IDE.

The `::` operator is known as the *scope resolution operator*, and it is used to get from a namespace or class to one of its members.

The `.` and `->` operators are for accessing an object instance's members, and only comes into play after creating an object instance. You use `.` if you have an actual object (or a reference to the object, declared with `&` in the declared type), and you use `->` if you have a pointer to an object (declared with `*` in the declared type).

The `this` object is always a pointer to the current instance, hence why the `->` operator is the only one that works.

Examples:

```
// In a header file
namespace Namespace {
    class Class {
        private:
            int x;
        public:
            Class() : x(4) {}
            void incrementX();
    };
}

// In an implementation file
namespace Namespace {
    void Class::incrementX() {    // Using scope resolution to get to the class member when we aren't using an instance
        ++(this->x);              // this is a pointer, so using ->. Equivalent to ++((*this).x)
    }
}

// In a separate file lies your main method
int main() {
    Namespace::Class myInstance;   // instantiates an instance. Note the scope resolution
    Namespace::Class *myPointer = new Namespace::Class;
    myInstance.incrementX();       // Calling a function on an object instance.
    myPointer->incrementX();       // Calling a function on an object pointer.
    (*myPointer).incrementX();     // Calling a function on an object pointer by dereferencing first

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

-> is for pointers to a class instance

. is for class instances

:: is for classnames - for example when using a static member

Answer (score 2):

The '::' is for static members.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the different syntaxes, but please note, when you are doing your `couts`, you are only using `->`:

```
int main()
{
    Kwadrat* kwadrat = new Kwadrat(1,2,3);
    cout<<kwadrat->val1<<endl;
    cout<<kwadrat->val2<<endl;
    cout<<kwadrat->val3<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```