# Access operators in C++

Tags: c++, operators

I'm in a course of C++, I found this a little bit confusing.

We're studying structs, and, if we create a new object from that structure, we can access to its properties using for example `foo.property`, but I found that to access to the struct statements, they use the `::` operator, and I only found a difference between `.`and `::` in the object they are accessing, but reading a little more about `::`, I found that you can access to global context's variables or functions using `::property`, but that's what I don't get, that it means that doing `class::property` is accessing to that property to the global context of the program, or is accessing to the global property inside the class, like doing `obj.property`?

So, what are the differences between `.` and `::`?

I come from JavaScript, so for my this is a little bit complex, and I didn't found a clear answer for this, and I don't found a clear response about what is `::`in general and its use.

Comment: Holy run-on, batman! Anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c

Comment: You need to read about namespaces and static members/functions in C++

Comment: Yeah, I get it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902791/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-c Thanks! I don't know why is so difficult found information about this, if there's post about that here :S

Comment: Yay! :D cool. Keep learning and let's rule the software world!