# C++ Class Constructor Arguments From Limited List

Tags: c++

I am wondering what was the best way using C++ to make a class constructor take an argument from a limited list. For example, if I have a class called `Colour`, then the constructor would only accept `Red`, `Green`, or `Blue` and store the value to a private variable. Then I would have a method called `printColour` which would print the variable.

Currently, I've been able to get this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef enum { A = 3, B = 7 } Options_t;
    MyClass(Options_t);
    void printVal(void);
private:
    Options_t _val;
};

MyClass::MyClass(Options_t val)
{
    _val = val;
}

void MyClass::printVal(void)
{
    cout << _val << endl;
}

MyClass hi(MyClass::A);

int main(void)
{
    hi.printVal();
    return 0;
}
```

However, the `::` notation to access the class's struct seems a bit clunky (I want to write an Arduino Library so it might be beginners needing to use the constructor / methods.

Is there any better way to do this (maybe with `.` notation?) Thanks!

**Edit:** When I try to compile with `MyClass x(2)` (`int` instead of `Options_t`), I get this error:

```
class_enums.cpp:24:9: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'MyClass'
MyClass hi(2);
        ^  ~
class_enums.cpp:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'int' to 'const MyClass' for 1st argument
class MyClass
      ^
class_enums.cpp:14:10: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to
      'MyClass::Options_t' for 1st argument
MyClass::MyClass(Options_t val)
         ^
```

So it seems that I can't just use an int as the argument?

Comment: Using “::” is appropriate. However, how do you present me from doing “MyClass x(2)”?

Comment: C++ is a verbose language. Personally I believe that using the clunky notation keeps things simple and clear.

Comment: @VladFeinstein the constructor only accepts an instance of the struct Options_t. Unless there's something I don't understand?

Comment: Look up the difference between `enum` and `enum class`. `enum` is the old way and will generally implicitly convert from numbers (so Vlad's snippet will work), whereas `enum class` is more strict in what it accepts.

Comment: If I try to compile with `MyClass x(2);`, I get these errors: `class_enums.cpp:25:9: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'MyClass'
MyClass x(2);
        ^ ~
class_enums.cpp:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known
      conversion from 'int' to 'const MyClass' for 1st argument
class MyClass
      ^
class_enums.cpp:14:10: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to
      'MyClass::Options_t' for 1st argument
MyClass::MyClass(Options_t val)
         ^
1 error generated.`

Comment: It seems that it prevents me from using a number in the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! In the end I decided to go with this code (below) because according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/enumerations-cpp?view=msvc-160) link, `ints` are not implicitly converted to an enum value.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef enum { C = 1, D = 6 } Options;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Options);
    void printVal(void);
private:
    Options _val;
};

MyClass::MyClass(Options val)
{
    _val = val;
}

void MyClass::printVal(void)
{
    cout << _val << endl;
}

MyClass hi(C);

int main(void)
{
    hi.printVal();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, doing it this way, I can define a `struct` for all the Options for the class, then just pass by reference to the constructor, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef enum { C = 1, D = 6 } Options;
typedef struct
{
    Options opt;
} MCConfig;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(Options);
    MyClass(MCConfig &);
    void printVal(void);
private:
    Options _val;
};

MyClass::MyClass(Options val)
{
    _val = val;
}

MyClass::MyClass(MCConfig & conf)
{
    _val = conf.opt;
}

void MyClass::printVal(void)
{
    cout << _val << endl;
}

MyClass hi(C);

int main(void)
{
    hi.printVal();
    MCConfig c;
    c.opt = D;
    MyClass m(c);
    m.printVal();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want this during creation of hi, then you can do

```
MyClass hi(hi.A);
```

However, in your class, you must use the namespace accessor `::`. The `.` is to access a member of an instance, not the actual class stuff.

They probably explained it better here: [When do I use a dot, arrow, or double colon to refer to members of a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984600/when-do-i-use-a-dot-arrow-or-double-colon-to-refer-to-members-of-a-class-in-c) and here: [What is the difference between "::" "." and "->" in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902791/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-c)