# Why compiler produces an error on template function

Tags: c++, stl, vector, set, containers

Why following code works fine:

```
template <typename Set, typename Vector> void copySetToVector2(Set &s, Vector &v)
{
    copy(s.begin(), s.end(), inserter(v, v.begin()));
}

int main()
{
    set<int> s1;
    s1.insert(1);
    s1.insert(2);
    s1.insert(3);

    vector<int> v1;

    copySetToVector2(s1, v1);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I change variables to pointers in template function compiler produces error:

> 'std::set< int >*' is not a class, struct, or union type

What is wrong here?

Comment: You mean when you change `Set &s, Vector &v` to `Set *s, Vector *v` you get this error?

Comment: Your compiler says "What is wrong here?" Laziest compiler ever!

Comment: @KerrekSB oops, my edit made your comment less funny. :)

Comment: Works here: template <typename Set, typename Vector> void copySetToVector2(Set* s, Vector* v)
{
    copy(s->begin(), s->end(), inserter(*v, v->begin()));
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change this:

```
template <typename Set, typename Vector> void copySetToVector2(Set &s, Vector &v)
```

to this:

```
template <typename Set, typename Vector> void copySetToVector2(Set *s, Vector *v)
```

then the body needs to look like this:

```
template <typename Set, typename Vector> void copySetToVector2(Set *s, Vector *v)
{
    copy(s->begin(), s->end(), inserter(*v, v->begin()));
}
```

The dot notation `s.begin()` does not work for pointers.  You need to switch to `s->begin()`.  See [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c) for more details.