# About struct and pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, heap-memory

I would like to create a linked list.

For the following code:

```
struct sampleStruct
{
    int a;
    sampleStruct *next = NULL;
};
sampleStruct *sample = new sampleStruct;
```

What is the difference between `sample.next` and `sample->next`?

Comment: Why don't you try then both and find out?

Comment: Only one of them would compile :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Comment: The first one is when you have a struct (or a class) the second is when you have a pointer to a struct (or class).

Comment: I understand now, thank you for your help :)
I will do some research before asking next time, I have lost so many marks (cry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay to explain it in a more complete way. The most other guys had already wrote that you have to use '->' when ever you have a pointer. But you could also do this with '.', to do this you must respect the priority of the operators. We need the '*' to get the content of the pointer, but this has a lower priority than the '.', so you must write it into brackets to give it a higher priority, so when you want to do this with a '.' you have to wrote:

```
(*sample).next
```

and you see this is a complex syntax, to do this in a more easy way the '->' was introduced. With it you could write code in a more comfortable way.

So this is is equal to the example and it looks much better.

```
sample->next
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `sample` is a pointer, there can't be any way to access a data member through `.` rather than the indirection operator `->`. For example, this won't compile:

```
sample.next; // error: member reference type 'sampleStruct *' is a pointer;
             //        maybe you meant to use '->'?
```

The error actually speaks for itself.