# C++ iterator operator precedence issue *it.method() vs (*it).method() vs it->method()

Tags: c++, iterator

This code won't compile:

```
for(vector<Box>::iterator it = shapes.end(); it >= shapes.begin(); --it){
    *it.update(1,1);
    *it.draw();
}
```

It claims:

```
main.cpp:80:17: error: ‘std::vector<Box>::iterator’ has no member named ‘update’
main.cpp:81:17: error: ‘std::vector<Box>::iterator’ has no member named ‘draw’
```

However AFAIK, that code doesn't try and call vector::iterator.draw(), it dereferences the iterator, which should give me an object of my class box, which does have those methods.
What am I doing wrong, and sorry for the awful title.

Comment: Beware of precedence. `*it.update(1,1);` is not the same as `(*it).update(1,1);`, which could written as `it->update(1,1);` for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a matter of operator precedence.

Operator `.` has higher precedence than operator `*`. Use parenthesis to force operator `*` application first.

```
(*it).update(1,1);
(*it).draw();
```

You can also use `operator ->` on iterators.

```
it->update(1,1);
it->draw();
```

Also see: [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c) and [cppreference: Member access operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access).

---

@andre stated correctly that you can also use reverse iterators to iterate over a sequence in reverse order but you should use them correctly.

```
for(vector<Box>::reverse_iterator it = shapes.rbegin(); it != shapes.rend(); ++it)
{
  it->update(1,1);
  it->draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, I take it that it was trying to call the update method of iterator, and then dereference the output of that. I will accept ASAP.

Comment: You're right. (Such issues are much harder to find if the reversed order of the operators compiles. (If any overloaded `operator *` of type A returns an object of type B which has a member function with the same signature as A...)

Answer (score 1):

**also**, to add on @Pixelchemist 's answer.

```
for(vector<Box>::iterator it = shapes.end(); it >= shapes.begin(); --it){
    *it.update(1,1);
    *it.draw();
}
```

**should be:**

```
for(vector<Box>::reverse_iterator it = shapes.rbegin(); it != shapes.rend(); ++it){
    *it.update(1,1);
    *it.draw();
}
```

`rend` and `rbeing` are used to iterate in reverse.

Comment: If you replace the type of `it` by `reverse_iterator` and iterate until `it!=shapes.rend()` then your example is correct (finally^^) ;)

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixed another problem I was having.

Comment: You're loop condition is still using `operator >=`. Since an end iterator is one-past the end of the data per definition, the `=` would result in undefnied behaviour, even if `>` would be correct, (which is not the case). If you do not want to use `!=` then replace `>=` by `<` (which is in fact the exact opposite `!(>=)` since reverse_iterator is the opposite of the iterator so you'll have to reverse the condition as well.)