# Creating a pointer of a struct in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

i have a struct defined as

```
typedef struct  BSP_AREA {

    struct BSP_AREA  *otherBspArea;         /* Pointer to itself */
    long             BSPReturnCode;                
    short            sGroupNum;             /* default to 0 */
    char             filler4[6];            /* alignment bytes */
    unsigned char    byCobolWorkArea[20];   /* Cobol Work Area */
    // .... and lots of others fields

} * PBSP_PASS ;
```

So basically a `BSP_AREA` can hold a pointer reference to itself, to create a sort of link list.

In the code, i have a method `createNode()` which returns a `BSP_AREA` with method signature `BSP_AREA createNode()`. So in this method i just initialize a `BSP_AREA` and return it. Now after calling this method, to set the pointer it contains to itself i am doing this, but getting an error.

```
BSP_AREA cobolPassArea2 = createNode(data1);
cobolPassArea->otherBspArea = &cobolPassArea2;
```

How do i initialize the pointer otherBSP to the `BSP_PASS_AREA` returned from `createNode()`? Please dont advise to make createNode return a pointer, instead of a concrete `BSP_AREA`, as this is the requirement.

Comment: is this `C` or `C++`? If it's `C++` there's no need for the typedef.

Comment: C++.............................

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It's hard to suggest an answer. However, in creating linked lists, using a pointer to an object that is not allocated in the heap sounds problematic. You can end with a dangling pointer very soon.

Comment: "/vob/infra_dev/source/cppsrc/sourcefile.cpp", line 550.16: 1540-0202 (S) An expression of type "BSP_AREA" is not allowed on the left side of "->".

Comment: Use a "." rather than a "->"

Comment: @OMGtechy it's a pointer typedef, so `PBSP_PASS` is different to `BSP_AREA`, but I agree that there is no need for it!

Comment: If you want to make a linked list then use `std::list` .

Answer (score 1):

```
cobolPassArea->otherBspArea = &cobolPassArea2;
```

should be

```
cobolPassArea2.otherBspArea = &cobolPassArea2;
```

Notice that the `->` has been changed to a `.`, in addition to adding the `2` to the variable name, on the left side.

Comment: I've edited in the points about what was changed. It would probably help to also explain the difference between the `->` and `.` operators there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef struct  BSP_AREA 
{

  struct BSP_AREA  *otherBspArea;   
  int something;
} *PBSP_PASS ;


struct BSP_AREA create()
{
   BSP_AREA x;
   x.something = 5;
   return x;
}
```

// this main you need to force the compiler to accept (-fpermissive on g++)

```
int main()
{
   BSP_AREA s;
   s.otherBspArea = &(create());
   printf("%d", s.otherBspArea->something);
}
```

// this one should work fine... but still, those requirements are a little odd

```
 int main()
{
   BSP_AREA s, r;
   r = create();
   s.otherBspArea = &r;
   printf("%d", s.otherBspArea->something);
}
```

Is that what you want? This compiles with a warning: "taking address of temporary"

Comment: It's not permitted to do `&(create())`, if your compiler generates an executable then it is a compiler extension.

Comment: i use g++... Well, c sort of let you do almost anything you want... It gave a warning tho (g++ -fpermissive file.cpp), and didn't compile without -fpermissive

Comment: @vmp: It didn't compile without permissive, because _it's not permitted to compile that code_.

Comment: yes I know that... that's why I posted 2 mains... And those requiriments are little bit weird... I wouldn't do either way