# Why did the C++ designers choose not to allow non-member operator()()?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, c++14

I am just playing with `std::function<>` and `operator`s, to make C++ statements look like Functional Languages(`F#`) and found out that there is a difference between `operator()` and `operator<<`. My code :

Function 1 (Operator Overload):

```
function<int(int)> operator>>(function<int(int)> f1, function<int(int)> f2)
{
  function<int(int)> f3 = [=](int x){return f1(f2(x));};
  return f3;
}
```

Function 2 (Operator Overload):

```
function<int(int, int)> operator>>(function<int(int, int)> f1, function<int(int)> f2)
{
  function<int(int, int)> f3 = [=](int x,int y){return f2(f1(x, y));};
  return f3;
}
```

Function 3 (Operator Overload):

```
function<int(int)> operator()(function<int(int, int)> f1, int x)
{
  function<int(int)> f2 = [=](int y){return f1(x, y);};
  return f2;
}
```

while the Function 1 and Function 2 ( or Operator Overload ), Function 3 gives out error that :

```
error: ‘std::function<int(int)> operator()(std::function<int(int, int)>, int)’ must be a nonstatic member function
     function<int(int)> operator()(function<int(int, int)> f1, int x)
                                                                    ^
```

Why do `operator()` needs to be non-static member?
I think its different than [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c) In that question the answer is explained in terms of pointers. But here I am using simple `operator()` and `operator>>`, which has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

Comment: So your question is "Why did the C++ designers choose not to allow non-member `operator()()`?"  If so, replace your title with that.

Comment: Every free function is a non member operator(). You don't need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the rules that the language designers decided on. `operator()` allows for a syntax which looks like it is part of the class itself (`std::function` in your case) and the interface of that class should be controlled by the class itself.

The standard defines this in

> #### 13.5.4 Function call [over.call]
>
> <sup>1</sup> `operator()` shall be a **non-static member function** with an arbitrary number of parameters. [...]

*emphasis mine*

Similar decisions were made for other operators like assignment `=`, subscripting `[]` and class member access `->`, while for operators like `>>`, they decided that it makes sense to allow adding operators between two (almost) arbitrary classes independently of the class' interface itself.

Answer (score 2):

`operator>>()` can be called as a non-static member or as a standalone function, depending on how it is defined for the left-hand data type.  The statement:

```
lhs >> rhs
```

Can resolve as either:

```
lhs.operator>>(rhs) // non-static member
```

Or:

```
operator>>(lhs, rhs) // standalone function
```

`operator()`, on the other hand, cannot be called as a standalone function.  It must have something on the left-hand side to invoke it.  The statement:

```
lhs(arguments)
```

Can only resolve as:

```
lhs(arguments) // only if lhs is an actual function
```

Or:

```
lhs.operator()(arguments) // must be a non-static member
```

There is no C++ language syntax that would allow the statement:

```
lhs(arguments)
```

to resolve as:

```
operator()(lhs, arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator>>()` can be overloaded as a non-member function but not `operator()`. `operator()` can only be a non-static member function of a `class` or a `struct`.

From the standard:

> **13.5.4 Function call**  [over.call]
>
> 1 `operator()` shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters. It can have default arguments. It implements the function call syntax
>
> *postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )*
>
> where the *postfix-expression* evaluates to a class object and the possibly empty *expression-list* matches the parameter list of an `operator()` member function of the class. Thus, a call `x(arg1,...)` is interpreted as `x.operator()(arg1, ...)` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator()(T1, T2, T3)` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3.3).