# Data structure and algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have these two functions:

```
void MakeNull_List(List L){
      L->Last=0;
}

void Empty_List(List L){
      return L.Last==0;
}
```

So, can anyone explain this code for me?  What is the difference between `L->Last` and `L.Last`?

Comment: You have a function with `void` return type `return L.Last==0;`? Where is this code coming from?

Comment: A single `=` assigns a value, while `==` tests for equality. You might want to read [a book about C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn more about this.

Comment: this code is coming from my document's lecturer. and i don't understand this

Comment: Just pick a good C++ book it should help you to understand this kind of basic concepts.

Comment: If that's your lecturer's code, you most definitely want to follow the suggestion from @redobot

Comment: At least one of `L->Last` and `L.Last` is wrong, but it's impossible to tell which without seeing the definition of `List`.

Comment: (`->` and/or `.` might be overloaded for `List`. _amit_ is spot-on pointing out the incongruity of `void` and `return`.) The sole purpose of this snippet may be to stress the indispensability of in-line comments: _code will get separated from external documentation_.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this code does NOT come from your lecturer, otherwise you should look for another one...

Sadly this code doesn't make sense because it is wrong! But I think you meant the following:

```
void MakeNull_List(List *L){    //* added
    L->Last=0;
}

bool Empty_List(List L){        //changed to bool
    return (L.Last==0);         //Please also use brackets here
}
```

The first function sets the last element to 0 (NULL) whathever sense it should make?!? The second function checks whether the last element is 0 (NULL) or not.

And your actual question: `->` is used to Access properties of a pointer to an object and `.` accesses the properties directly of the object. For more info read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you access object by variable or reference you should address to it fields by `.`. 
Then you have a pointer to object you should previously dereference it. So, you can write `(*ptr).someField` or `ptr->someField`.

I think, you miss `*` in `void MakeNull_List(List *L)` definition.