# Play with elements of Array of Structures in C++

Tags: c++

I have just started learning c++ and I am stuck over here.
I made a structure

```
...
struct student{
string name;
int roll;
};
...
```

And then, I called it globally. `student s1[20];` Inside my main function, 
I did something like this

```
...
int count=0;
student *p;
p=s1;
cout<<"Enter the Number of records, you wish to consider.";
cin>>arraySize;
p = new student[arraySize];
while (count!=arraySize) {
    cout<<"Enter name.";
    cin>>*(p+count)->name; //Error comes over here
}
...
```

The error message, I get is `Indirection requires pointer operand`. Can some one Please help me out with this ??

Comment: cin>>*(p+count)->name; change to this cin >> (p + count)->name; 
*(p + count)->name; resultin in dereference a var that not an address and cause error, you just want to fill the var, so just do it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either use pointer arithmetic as you are doing

```
(p+count)->name
```

or more canonically use `[]` to index into the array

```
p[count].name
```

The reason you are getting an error is because you are combining `*` which dereferences your pointer with `->` which also dereferences your pointer. You could just do one or the other

```
(p+count)->name
(*(p+count)).name
```

Though as I said for readability I would prefer using index notation `[]`

Comment: `*(p+count).name` is incorrect. `.` has higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: `(*(p+count).)name` is also incorrect. The closing bracket should be before the `.`, not after it.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Still only half-way through my coffee this morning :) should be squared away now

Comment: If I ever saw `(*(foo)).bar`, I wouldn't be alright.

Answer (score 2):

Using `*(p+count)->name` makes no sense.

Picking up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c), `foo->bar` calls method `bar` on the object pointed by pointer `foo`.

So, you should either do `(p+count)->name` or `(*(p+count)).name`.

Note the brackets, they're necessary as `.` has greater precedence than `*`.