# Should I prefer the dot (.) or arrow (->) operator for accessing pointer members in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

As I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c/1238643#1238643), for a pointer `p` there are two equivalent ways of accessing a member of the referenced object, namely `p->foo` and `(*p).foo`.

Are there technical arguments which is best to use?

**Note:** One argument I read about, is that `.` is safer because it cannot be overloaded, while `->` can. I guess, however, there must be more arguments, as in most C++ code I work on I only see the `->`-construct.

Comment: `*` can also be overloaded.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read. You will be fine.

Comment: this is an opinionated question, there is no real answer. Just continue coding and decide for yourself

Comment: But if you decide that doing `(*p).foo` everywhere is more readable you're wrong ;-)

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I ask for technical arguments (as I gave one in the note). For example overloadbility is a hard fact. I consider it appropriate to ask for hard facts that I will use for a soft decision.

Comment: @KerrekSB OK, I meant that `.` cannot be overloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For raw pointers, operators cannot be overloaded.

For smart pointers, the `operator *` can be overloaded as well and should return the same object as `operator ->` (although dereferenced).

The `operator ->` is IMO much better readable than wrapping everything in parentheses, especially when you would use it multiple times in a row.

There is a slight difference that `operator ->` is chained (`operator ->` is called on the returned object and it can again be overloaded) while `operator *` is not but it is unusual to have a situation where this would end in different results.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, both approaches do the same thing:

```
p->member
(*p).member
```

except for situations where you overload operators to get a specialized behavior.

As far as which is 'better' it depends on what better means...
`p->member` is a lot cleaner and makes the code easier to understand, which is always a big plus.

Take a more complicated example:

```
struct NewType
{
   int data;
}

void foo (NewType **p)
{
   int temp0 = (*p)->data;
   int temp1 = (*(*p)).data;
}
```

both `temp0` and `temp1` will have the same value, but it's a lot easier to see what's going on for `temp0`.