# Get value from private std::map

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm starting with C++ and I'm trying to expand std::map class via composition.
I want to use this class `CardPackage` to have a private map of ids and pointers to my `EntityCards` and implement three methods `AddCard`, `GetCard` and `RemoveCard` that will access the private map `m`.

The issue is that I have not been able to work with `m` methods (`find` and `end`) because I get the following error message:

`expression must have a pointer type`

I understand that `m` needs to be a pointer to be accessed by arrow notation (or dot) but I can't figure out to adapt the code to respect my requirements.

Header:

```
#include <EntityCard.h>

class CardPackage
{
public:

CardPackage();
~CardPackage();

void AddCard(EntityCard* card);
EntityCard* GetCard(int id);
bool RemoveCard(int id);

private:
    map<int, EntityCard*> m;
};
```

Source:

```
#include "CardPackage.h"

CardPackage::CardPackage()
{
}


CardPackage::~CardPackage()
{
}

   void CardPackage::AddCard(EntityCard *card)
   {
        m[card->ID] = card;
   }

EntityCard* CardPackage::GetCard(int id)
{
    if (id < 1) { return nullptr; }
    if(m->find(id) == m->end())
    {
        return (m[id]);
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

bool CardPackage::RemoveCard(int id)
{
    //TODO
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   if(m->find(id) == m->end())
```

Should be:

```
   if(m.find(id) != m.end())
```

`m` is not a pointer, so you need `.`, rather than `->`.  You also have the test the wrong way round.

A slightly better implementation would be:

```
   const auto it = m.find(id);
   if (it != m.end())
       return it->second;
   else
       return nullptr;
```

The difference is that this only does one lookup in the map, whereas your code does two.

Comment: I wrongly assumed . (dot) and -> (arrow) were the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c

Comment: @Sturm they are not. Usually only `->` or `.` can be applied depending on whether you apply it to a pointer or an object. However, there are some "hybrid" types that implement both (e.g. smartpointers)

Comment: @Martin wouldn't it be `return it->second;` ? I get an error if I just return *it