# pointer c++ on objects and variables

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

since I am currently learning pointers in C++, I am wondering about the syntax. So when I want to use a pointer on an object, I do not have to dereference it, in order to access the class attributes. When I just want to use a pointer on a simple variable, I have to use * for changing its values.

So why do I not have to use the * for the object? Because so I thought I would just change the memory address.

Object:

```
int age = 20;
User John(age);    
User *ptrUser = &John;

ptrUser->printAge(); // 20 (why no *ptrUser->printAge()  ??? )
cout << ptrUser // 0x123456...
```

Variables:

```
int a = 10;
int *ptrA = &a;   
*ptrA = 20;  
cout << a // 20
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: So this is not C.

Comment: Did you study what `->` mean?

Comment: You might want to step back and [find a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It seems to me that you're not noticing that "." and "->' are different operators.

Comment: var->Foo() is (*var).Foo()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to dereference the pointer, the `->` operator is just syntactic sugar for dereference-and-member-access:

Instead of

```
ptrUser->printAge();
```

you could write

```
(*ptrUser).printAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

There can actually be two things:

1. You aren't aware about the [`->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238643/2172854):

As @alain pointed out in his answer, `->` is mere syntactic sugar and can be replaced with a `*` and `.` as:

```
(*ptrUser).printAge();
```

2. You are aware about the `->` operator and wondering why not `*ptrUser->printAge()`:

Here, when you say `*ptrUser = &John;`, you are storing the address of `John` in a pointer variable called `ptrUser`.  In other words, `ptrUser` points to `John`.  So, when you want to access the member function `printAge()` of `John`, you can simply do:

```
ptrUser->printAge();
```

because `ptrUser` is already pointing to `John`.

Hope this is helpful.