# Shared_ptr indirection: Difference between (*a).b and a->b?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

To my knowledge, `foo->bar()` is the same as `(*foo).bar()`, except when the arrow is overloaded in a weird way, which usually should not be done. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1238643/4629950) seems to concur.

This however seems to not be true for boost::shared_ptrs. Above are two lines of my code that yield different results in some cases:

```
(*new_link).getRefNode()  // returns some value
new_link->getRefNode()    // returns something different...
```

What am I missing / not understanding here?

Edit: As requested, the cout code and what gets printed. I made sure that getRefNode() does not modify the instance in any way - if I change the order of the calls, the values change with the calls, so it's not about anything that getRefNode() does internally.

```
    std::cout << "BLink1: " << (*previous_link).getId().toStdString()
              << ", ref: " << (*previous_link).getRefNode()
              << ", nref: " << (*previous_link).getNrefNode()
              << std::endl << "Link2: " << (*new_link).getId().toStdString()
              << ", ref: " << (*new_link).getRefNode()
              << ", nref: " << (*new_link).getNrefNode() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New link: " << new_link->getId().toStdString()
              << ", ref: " << new_link->getRefNode()
              << ", nref: " << new_link->getNrefNode() << std::endl;
```

> BLink1: 1076889319, ref: (48.68674, 8.99122), nref: (48.68682, 8.99368)
>
> Link2: 1076570435, **ref: (48.68674, 8.99122), nref: (48.68682, 8.99368)**
>
> New link: 1076570435, ref: (48.68669, 8.98889), nref: (48.68674, 8.99122)

(Highlights by me)

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: How have you tested this return value?

Comment: My problem is that I have no idea what causes this, so I cannot write a minimal verifiable example...

Comment: @Stefan: Not sure what you mean. I do a cout on the return value and it yields, in some out of many cases, different results. Most of the time it works as expected.

Comment: Can you post the code with the `cout`? It might add some relevance.

Comment: I appended it to my question.

Comment: Tell me: If you reverse the order of the calls (i.e. call `->` first) do the values in the third line move to the second?

Comment: Is that possible that you have modified some value by accident between two `cout`? Are 2 `cout` consecutive?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, they do. I tried calling the "Link2" line again afterwards to be sure and it still delivers the wrong results, so it is not about the order...

Comment: @CWliu: No, nothing happens between the couts, I execute this part of the Code as posted...

Comment: Well, `boost::shared_ptr<T>` returns a `T*` when `operator->` is applied to it. Such a perturbation seems to me like an indicator of UB somewhere in your class.

Comment: `operator*` returns a reference and `operator->` returns a pointer which ought to point at the same thing. If you suspect that it in fact points at something else, print it together with the address of the result of `operator*` and verify. If they are the same, then `operator*` and ``operator->` work correctly and the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: If you don't chain the `<<`s, do you get the same result?

Comment: @n.m.: How would you print what operator-> returns? I tried it with, but operator-> returns an r-value, it has no address...

Comment: @molbdnilo: Thanks for that suggestion. They print the correct thing if they are not chained... Which is still confusing for me. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Thomas Then one or more of the function must have a side effect that affects the result of some of the others. The order of evaluation of operands (like all function arguments) is unspecified, so you need to be careful about that.

Comment: Hm, so what is the correct procedure on SO for this? Completely edit my question, or close this one and open a new one? I still don't know why this happens, but it's not about * and -> any more...

Comment: What operator-> returns *is* an address. You print *it*. `cout << smartptr.operator->();`.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, I just read about that. I tried it and they do indeed return the same address, which means the problem is in the chaining and not in -> and *. I'll close this question and ask a new one since I would have to edit too much here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is not in the difference between (*a) and a->, but in chaining them together in the same cout. Doing `cout << a->func() << b->func();` yields different results from `cout << a->func(); cout <<b->func();`.

I'll open a new question for that.