# When to use arrow and when dot?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I've read about it and I mostly get it, but this situation confused me a bit. Why don't we use arrow operator `->` in `scanf`? I understand that dot is used for objects and arrow for pointers but here, `g` is a pointer to structure.

```
DOCUMENT *take(int *pn){
        DOCUMENT *g;
        printf("How much documents? ");
        scanf("%d", pn);
        g = (DOCUMENT *)calloc(*pn, sizeof(DOCUMENT));
        for (int i = 0; i < *pn; i++)
        {
            printf("Type in author, name of document and number of pages: ");
            scanf("%s %s %d", g[i].author, g[i].name, &g[i].s );
        }
        return g;
    }
```

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). If you replace `g[i].author` with `g[i]->author` your code won't compile. Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and -> in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array index operator `[]` has a dereference built into it.

`g[i]` is exactly the same as `*(g + i)`.  So `g[i]` refers to a `DOCUMENT`, not a `DOCUMENT *` and thus you use the member access operator `.` instead of the pointer-to-member operator `->`.

Answer (score 2):

If the left operand of the `.` or `->` is a pointer, then you use `->`. Otherwise if it is an object (plain variable), then you use `.`.

In this case `g[i]` is taking a pointer and doing array subscripting on it. The result of that is an object ("lvalue"), not a pointer, hence `g[i].`.

---

Also note operator precedence in expressions like `&g[i].s`. The array subscripting operator `[]` and the struct member operator `.` have same operator precedence - they belong to the same group of postfix operators. But that group has left-to-right *operator associativity* so `[]` takes precedence over the `.`. Then after those two follow `&`, the unary address operator, with lowest operator precedence in the expression. So operator precedence guarantees that the expression is equivalent to `&((g[i]).s)`.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript operator used with a pointer yields the object pointed to by the pointer expression. That is, for example, this expression

```
g[i].author
```

(where `g[i]` is the `i-th` element of the array of structures) is equivalent to

```
( g + i )->author
```

where `g + i` is a pointer that points to the `i-th` element of the array of structures.

The subscript operator `g[i]` is equivalent to the expression `*( g + i )`.

You may write

```
g[i].author
```

or like

```
( *( g + i ) ).author
```

or like

```
( g + i )->author
```

Thus this call of scanf

```
scanf("%s %s %d", g[i].author, g[i].name, &g[i].s );
```

can be rewritten like

```
scanf("%s %s %d", ( g + i )->author, ( g + i )->name, &( g + i )->s );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write g[i], this is actually equal to *(g + i). That is, you dereference the pointer and it becomes an object again, so you can access it with dot (.) instead of arrow (->).