# What does "->" stand for in C programming, Gtk+ programming?

Tags: c, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the arrow operator (->) synonym for in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-is-the-arrow-operator-synonym-for-in-c)

I couldn't find documentation on the "->" which is used a lot in Gnome codebase. For example in gedit they have this:

```
loader->document = g_value_get_object (value)
```

What is document in relation to loader? There are many other examples as well with more basic widgets as well.

Comment: Dupe, many times (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-is-the-arrow-operator-synonym-for-in-c - Yes, it's a C++ question, but it's the same operator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`loader` is a pointer. `->` dereferences a pointer to a struct. It's the same as typing `(*loader).`

Hence:

```
struct smth {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct smth blah;
struct smth* pblah;
```

...to get access to `a` from `blah`, you need to type `blah.a`, from pblah you need to write `pblah->a`. Remember that it needs to point to something though!

Comment: Specifically, it is a pointer to a `struct`, and `->` accesses a member of the `struct` that it points to. It is equivalent to `(*loader).document` except for being shorter and clearer.

Comment: Actually, * dereferences a pointer.  -> dereferences a pointer and then accesses a field of the struct it pointed to.

Comment: `loader` could be an `union`.

Answer (score 8):

`loader->document` is same as: `(*loader).document`

Answer (score 5):

`loader` is a pointer to a `struct` or a `union`.  The `struct`/`union` has at least one member, named `document`:

```
struct astruct {
    T document;
};
```

`T` above is the type of `document`, and is also the type returned by `g_value_get_object()`.

Then, given the declarations below:

```
struct astruct s;
struct astruct *loader = &s;
```

the following are equivalent:

```
s.document = ...
loader->document = ...
(*loader).document = ...
```

Formally, `->` is a binary operator, whose first operand has a type "pointer to a structure or pointer to union", and the second operand is the name of a member of such a type.

Answer (score 3):

`loader` is a pointer to a struct that has a `document` field, `->` is used to access it.