# What does -> mean in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between the dot (.) operator and ->  in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238613/what-is-the-difference-between-the-dot-operator-and-in-c)
>   [What is the arrow operator (->) synonym for in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-is-the-arrow-operator-synonym-for-in-c)

The header says it all.

What does **->** mean in C++?

Comment: Which language are you familiar with?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean about "->" . It is just a deferencing stuff for accessing member variables and functions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's to access a member function or member variable of an object through a *pointer*, as opposed to a regular variable or reference.

For example: with a regular variable or reference, you use the `.` operator to access member functions or member variables.

```
std::string s = "abc";
std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
```

But if you're working with a pointer, you need to use the `->` operator:

```
std::string* s = new std::string("abc");
std::cout << s->length() << std::endl;
```

It can also be overloaded to perform a specific function for a certain object type.  Smart pointers like `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, as well as STL container iterators, overload this operator to mimic native pointer semantics.

For example:

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(), end = mymap.end();
for (; it != end; ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
```

Comment: 13 years later and this is the only answer here that actually explains it for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 54):

`a->b` means `(*a).b`.

If `a` is a *pointer*,  `a->b` is the member `b` of which `a` points to.

`a` can also be a pointer like object (like a `vector<bool>`'s stub) override the operators.

(if you don't know what a pointer is, you have another question)

Comment: Unless it's a class with the operator overloaded.

Comment: It's a shame this has so many votes, since overloading the operator is common and an important piece of the answer.

Comment: I don't know what (*a).b means.

Comment: @Steve: Anyone that overloads `a.operator->()` to be different from `&*a` is evil.

Comment: Steve, I also agree. While I appreciate the effort from J-16 SDiZ it seems like all the votes are probably coming from those who already understand clearly the answer. I will most likely accept an answer that is more descriptive.

Comment: @Roger - agreed.  I just think this needs color on overloading.

Answer (score 33):

1. Access operator applicable to (a) all pointer types, (b) all types which explicitely overload this operator
2. Introducer for the return type of a local lambda expression:

   ```
   std::vector<MyType> seq;
   // fill with instances...  
   std::sort(seq.begin(), seq.end(),
               [] (const MyType& a, const MyType& b) -> bool {
                   return a.Content < b.Content;
               });
   ```
3. introducing a trailing return type of a function in combination of the re-invented `auto`:

   ```
   struct MyType {
       // declares a member function returning std::string
       auto foo(int) -> std::string;
   };
   ```

Comment: +1 for the return types.

Comment: Don't forget #2 applies to all deduced return types (lambdas and non-lambdas).

Comment: Added to the abve enumeration. Don't know why the code examples do not show up correctly, if anybody knows what's going on, please feel free to correct the formatting.

Comment: After a list element, code has to be indented 8 spaces instead of 4. I also removed the trailing return type from the lambda, it's deduced.

Comment: @GMan Thanks, but I added it back, since otherwise that becomes quite irrelevant with respect to the OP's question :) I could not (rapidly) come up with a lambda whose return type cannot be deduced, so that trivial one shall serve as an example...

Comment: @paul_71: Oh, right. Though you've misplaced it.

Comment: @GMan Yeah, and corrected again... Now we keep it closed :-)

Answer (score 6):

x->y can mean 2 things. If x is a pointer, then it means member y of object pointed to by x.
If x is an object with operator->() overloaded, then it means x.operator->().

Comment: No. If x is an object with operator-> overloaded, it means x.operator->(), and if the return value also supports operator->, then it means x.operator->().operator->(). Operator-> takes no arguments.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators

`a -> b` is member *b* of object pointed to by *a*

Answer (score 2):

The `->` operator, which is applied exclusively to pointers, is needed to obtain the specified field or method of the object referenced by the pointer. (this applies also to `structs` just for their fields)

If you have a variable `ptr` declared as a pointer you can think of it as `(*ptr).field`.

A side node that I add just to make pedantic people happy: AS ALMOST EVERY OPERATOR you can define a different semantic of the operator by overloading it for your classes.

Comment: It does not apply exclusively to pointers because it can be overloaded as a class operator.  The shared pointer component does this as do iterators for containers in the standard library.

Comment: yes, of course it can be overloaded (as every operator) but I guess the OP needed to know the original semantics of the operator..

Answer (score 1):

member b of object pointed to by a
a->b