# "ptr = ptr - > next" What does this "->" mean? (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I use instead of the arrow operator, `-&gt;`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221346/what-can-i-use-instead-of-the-arrow-operator)
>   [What does -> mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113365/what-does-mean-in-c)

So I'm currently studying for a C++ exam about Data Structure and Algorithm Development. While looking though my teacher powerpoints, I've noticed that he's used this "->" a lot. And I'm not sure what it means? Is it really a command you can do in c++?

Example 1

```
addrInfo *ptr = head;
while (ptr->next != NULL) 
{
        ptr = ptr->next;
}   
// at this point, ptr points to the last item
```

Example 2

```
if( head == NULL )
{
head = block;
block->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Just an additional comment, the `->` operator is called the 'pointer to member' operator. I'm not sure why so many people don't have a name for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a combination dereference and member-access. This `ptr->next` is equivalent to `(*ptr).next`.

Answer (score 5):

The `->` operator deferences a pointer and retrieves from it the memory index beyond that point indicated by the following name.  Thus:

```
struct foo {
   int bar;
   int baz;
};

struct foo something;
struct foo *ptr = &something;

ptr->bar = 5;
ptr->baz = 10;
```

In the above, the `ptr` value will be the memory location of the `something` structure (that's what the `&` does: finds the memory location of `something`).  Then the `ptr` variable is later "dereferenced" by the `->` operator so that the `ptr->bar` memory location (an int) is set to 5 and `ptr->baz` is set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's de-referencing the pointer.  It means "Give me the value of the thing pointed at the address stored at `ptr`".  In this example, `ptr` is pointing to a list item so `ptr->next` returns the value of the object's `next` property.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator is specifically a *structure dereference*. In `block->next` it is calling the member variable `next` of the object which the pointer `block` points to. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) page for a list of member and pointer operators in C++.

Basically, it's doing the same thing as `block.next`, were `block` an object rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

-> is an operator of pointer. It is used for pointer to access member.

If you take a look at the defination of "addrInfo", you can find the member "next".

Otherwise, you can see the following example:

```
struct student
{
int num;
}
struct student stu;
struct student *p;
p=&stu;
```

These three operations are equal:
1. stu.num
2. (*P).num
3. p->num