# C++ Elegant way to implement assignment of different type using one method and without warning?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, assignment-operator

I have to implement basically the same function but for different size. Specifically it is something like...

```
type& operator=(unsigned int);
type& operator=(unsigned long int);
type& operator=(unsigned long long int);
type& operator=(int);
type& operator=(long int);
type& operator=(long long int);
type& operator=(short int);
//so on and so forth...
```

They have to do exactly the same thing... (except i should take into account the different size), the main idea would be "if the type is the widest use the code for the task... otherwise perform a casting and execute the code". Is it possible to avoid all such repetitive code by using only one method? (i just don't want the compiler throw me some warning when i compile...).

Thank you

Comment: Assignment from primitive integer types is problematic for various reasons, but if you must do it: have you tried just implementing the overloads for `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` (from `<cstdint>`)?

Comment: Yes i'm using cstdint, i just want to avoid to write all the same code... in elegant and efficient way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for all integral types:

```
template<
    typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>
>
type& operator= (T);
```

If you want to depend on size, it can be obtained with simply `sizeof(T)`. You can compare that with your biggest desired size.

If you wanted two separate functions, you'd need to put that clause in as well and use some sort of static-all.

Comment: Is there any alternative to templates? they're pretty hard to read.

Comment: @Lukkio Excuse me, but what do you find hard to read in this particular code? I think it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Could you forward me some reference on template syntax? My max in using template is <code>template <class T></code> or i specify a specific type for T.

Comment: @Lukkio [This link](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:enable-if-for-c-11) might help, as well as [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) documentation.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz `typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) == sizeof(long long)>::type* = nullptr` should work.

Comment: Or you could just have another overload which would be preferred to the template

Comment: @TartanLlama what do you mean?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz your use of template, your specific use i mean, is a feature of C++11, isn't?

Comment: @Lukkio `enable_if_t` was added in C++14.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz i don't understand the semantic of the syntax you've used. If i putted <code>template <class T, class V></code> it means i'm parametrizing two types what have you putted in the second argument of your template is a kind a proposition without a name i can't understand how to intepret it (but the idea is clear).

Comment: you can drop the `typename enable_if_t` since the `_t` already extracts the `::type`

Comment: @Lukkio this is just a way to put that clause in. SFINAE requires the function type to contain the check as either template parameter, return type or a parameter type. Either would work, I just prefer this form.

Comment: I prefer the anser by @SimonKraemer because it allows multiple overloads. Using SFINAE on default function template arguments is only for cases where you want to restrict to a single subset.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz so actually your code (very informally) should mean "apply the template if T is of integral type", isn't? you defined a parameter in the first argument, on the second you defined a kind of constraint on it ,is it?

Comment: would be possible to add a further condition that check the type is signed or not? if it is signed i would like to generate some code (the templates are a kind of macro afaik) otherwise generate other code.

Comment: @Lukkio yes, it is possible to check if the type is signed or not using something like `std::is_signed`. Please ask another question if you have issues implementing this.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the [answer of Bartek Banachewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737252/4181011) an alternative way to solve it:

```
struct type
{
    ////Solution by Bartek Banachewicz
    //template<typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
    //type& operator= (T) 
    //{ 
    //  return *this; 
    //}

    template<typename T>
    auto operator=(T) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, type>::type&
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: I feel that this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22515589/1614219 might be useful to those who (like me), don't know about the `->` syntax in signatures.

Comment: this answer is better because it allows multiple `std::enable_if` overloads (you can't change the default function template argument  )