# CLion gives false errors in analysis

Tags: c++, clion

For the code bellow:

```
auto main() -> int {
  char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  char * p = arr;
  char ** pp = &p;
  const char * const * p_const = pp;
}
```

Clion says that there is an error on the last line
`const char * const * p_const = pp;`

"Assigning 'char * *' to 'const char * const *' discards const qualifier"

AFAIK, this cast is allowed and the code compiles.

Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: No repro with gcc7.1 and clang4.0. Probably broken Apple-LLVM again, no idea why people keep using that...

Comment: Take a look at one of these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Btw I had to ask about that `auto main() -> int {}` sorcery and was told [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514855/arrow-operator-in-function-heading/22515589#22515589) has the answer.

Comment: @Ron Sorcery? That's just modern C++ trailing return type. Some 6 years old by now..

Comment: @JesperJuhl When used to represent a simple `int main()` it looks more like unnecessary obfuscation (sorcery) to me.

Comment: "CLion finds false error" - well, compilers are not fail safe you know. There are always going to be false positives with their error messages once in a while.

Comment: Do you get this error on compiling or in the editor as an analysis?

Comment: @IlyaPopov as an analysis. The code compiles well.