# Qt/Qt Creator and arrow operator (->) in function heading - is it working?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

**Using Qt Creator 4.10.2 and Qt 5.9/5.12**

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515589/1559401) since C++ 11 you can use the arrow operator in the function's heading. The coding conventions at my place of work currently require for all functions to be written like this.

My problem is that apparently Qt Creator doesn't support this when you auto-generate the definition of a function using refactoring (click on a function in header without definition to open context menu -> select Refactoring -> Add definition to xyz.cpp).

**Example:**
If you have declared a function inside your header

```
auto foo() -> void;
```

the auto-generated definition will be

```
void foo()
{
}
```

In addition to that apparently the **moc** generation in Qt doesn't like this style either when used for slots.

Is there a workaround or I just need to make exceptions for all the slots and also always either manually add the definition of a function to my source file or edit the auto-generated one? Perhaps I am missing some tweak in the settings of Qt Creator?

Comment: Which version of Qt and Qt Creator are you using?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude updated post. Sorry, forgot to add this vital piece of info.

Comment: That syntax is mostly meant to work around visibility problems. E.g. `template <class T> auto foo(typename std::vector<T>::iterator x) -> decltype(x)`. No reason to use it for something like slot

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Could be. Frankly never used it before (but read what it does here [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)) but I have to now. :D

Comment: @rbaleksander you're not trying to make template handler? Qt doesn't support that, they barely adapted for lambdas to be connect()-ed. If that's for sake of removing double type declarators, maybe a nested typedef is due

Comment: What about Qt Creator's refactoring tool? No support there either?

Comment: You have to add CONFIG += c++11 .pro file.
Maybe these will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator