# Use of -> in PHP and C++

Tags: php, c++

This is a very simple question, I'm trying to learn PHP and C++ and in both languajes I've see this -> , i kinda get the meaning,is like an asignation operator? but I haven't find the right answer.

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry if the question is too simple, i've searched far and wide in google but have not got a clear answer

Comment: Did you search it in your computer hard drive? There is one just google for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php

Comment: For the PHP part: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/3933332

Comment: And the other C++ part: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4113365/3933332

Comment: This is used to access property of an object in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to access properties on an object;

In PHP

```
class Car {
     public $make;
     public $model;

     public function setMake($make) {
          $this->make = $make;
     }

     public function setModel($model) {
          $this->model = $model;
     }

     public function getMake() {
          return $this->make;
     }

     public function getModel() {
          return $this->model;
     }

}

$car = new car();
$car->setMake("BMW");
$car->setModel("Three Series");

echo "Make: " . $car->getMake() . " Model: " . $car->getModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

The object operator, "->", is used in object scope to access methods and properties of an object.