# What does -> mean in c++11 in a function signature?

Tags: c++, c++11

Note this is NOT a duplicate of [What does -> mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113365/what-does-mean-in-c)

The question is specific to C++11; where a function can look like:

```
struct string_accumulator {
}


inline auto collect() -> string_accumulator
{
    return string_accumulator();
}
```

What is the meaning of the ->  in this context?

Comment: I didn't downwote, but I think your title could be more specific, like: "what(...) in function declaration?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [*trailing return type*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). It can be used to explicitly specify return types for *lambda expressions* or to specify return types that depend on a function's arugments. Examples:

```
[](int) -> float { return 0.f; };

template <typename A, typename B>
auto foo(A a, B b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```

Comment: It can also be a bit useful just to put the return type in the scope of the function.  Like instead of `MyNS::MyClass::MyNestedType MyNS::MyClass::f() { return {}; }`, you can do `auto MyNS::MyClass::f() -> MyNestedType { return {}; }`