# Changing values pointed to by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have the following code:

```
class Person {
    public:
      int age;
      string name;
};

int main() {
  Person ben;
  ben.age = 30;
  ben.name = "Ben";
  Person * ptrBen = &ben;

return 0;
}
```

If i want to change the value stored in the `age` variable of the `ben` object to `35` for example, I can write in `main()`:

```
ptrBen->age = 35;
```

Is there a difference between this and the following?:

```
(*ptrBen).age = 35;
```

Comment: `prtBen`, really? Also, you're missing parentheses: `(*ptrBen).age`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does -> mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113365/what-does-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever between `ptrBen->age = 35;` and `(*ptrBen).age = 35;` when `ptrBen` is a pointer. They do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference. `ptrBen->age = 35;` might be more readable though.